# pip setup and setting PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm not experienced in Python, and I need the `requests` module.

I've tried installing it using `pip install requests`

The installation went successfully, but when I try to import the module, I get an error like "no module named requests".

Should I add the install location to PYTHONPATH? If yes, how can I find the location where pip installed the files? I don't know about virtualenv, and I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: How do you install pip?, which is his location?`pip --version`

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-pip , version -> pip 0.8.2 from /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7 (python 2.7) [But I am using python3.1 console!!]

Comment: @cyraxjoe When I tried in Python2.7 console, Its working fine.But not in python3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install pip for python3 first 
[How to install pip with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)
then with the `pip-3.X` install the required module.

Comment: And just like eryksun comment, you cannot use `request` in python 3 yet.