# Install PIL in Ubuntu 12.04 Python 2.7 and Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am, using Ubuntu 12.04 server which by default has two versions of Python: 2.7 and 3.2. When I install PIL using the `python setup.py install` terminal command, the PIL will be installed with Python 2.7. How to install PIL with Python 3.2? Because I'm using Python 3 to write my script. If my Eclipse uses Python 2.7, PIL is successfully imported. But if I choose Python 3 as my Grammar language, PIL fails to import.

P/S: I have tried the following:

- [Pillow PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow#downloads) (Pillow-1.7.8.zip )
- [Aspell PIL](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil) (PIL-1.1.7-py3-source.zip)

**UPDATE:**

Using the `python3` command results in an error message.

Example 1:

```
root@sys:~/Downloads/Pillow-1.7.8# python3.2 setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    from setuptools import Extension, setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Example 2:

```
root@sys:~/Downloads/Pillow-1.7.8# python3 setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    from setuptools import Extension, setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

### UPDATE 2

After i have run this terminal command

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

i can build the setup.py already,but error message at last.

```
root@sys:~/Downloads/Pillow-1.7.8# python3 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 469, in <module>
    scripts=glob.glob("Scripts/pil*.py"),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 917, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 344, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "setup.py", line 127, in build_extensions
    self.add_multiarch_paths()
  File "setup.py", line 439, in add_multiarch_paths
    '/usr/lib/' + multiarch_path_component)
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

### UPDATE 3

Error message when use https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow this file

```
root@sys:~/Pillow-master# dir
COPYING              Images          map.c       selftest.py
decode.c             _imaging.c      outline.c   setup.py
display.c            _imagingcms.c   path.c      test
docs                 _imagingft.c    PIL         Tests
encode.c             _imagingmath.c  py3.h       Tk
github-comments.txt  _imagingtk.c    README.rst  tox.ini
github-issues.txt    libImaging      Sane
github-watchers.txt  MANIFEST.in     Scripts
root@sys:~/Pillow-master# python3 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageGL.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ArgImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/PIL
running build_ext
building '_imaging' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/libImaging
gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/usr/include/freetype2 -IlibImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.2mu -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/_imaging.o
_imaging.c:75:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

### SOLVED

follow the step to install

```
sudo aptitude install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
# download Pillow's master.zip
wget https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/archive/master.zip
sudo unzip master.zip
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install
```

DONE!

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip

Comment: @akaIDIOT so,after i setup source `py3env/bin/activate` use this command? `pip install setup.py` ?

Comment: I think they mean using `pip-3.2` as shown in that highly upvoted answer, virtualenv not needed ..  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12262143/674039

Comment: @wim then what is the package name? `sudo pip-3.2 install <package>`

Comment: Oow, I misread; PIL is the main point. I've managed to get the current github master of Pillow to build and run for python3. `python3 setup.py build` followed by `python3 setup.py install` should work i think, after cloning the repo. You should of course install the python3-version of setuptools, as the error points out (possibly `python3-distutils`, not on an ubuntu machine atm).

Comment: @akaIDIOT can't,see the above code,`python3 setup.py build` can't work,error message has shown above

Comment: For others, install the latest dev versions of Tcl/Tk and libraries for jpeg, zlib (png/zip), freetype2, and littlecms as necessary before you build. Also, make sure to run `python3 selftest.py` between the build and install steps to make sure everything works. Also, all of the commands require sudo except for the wget and selftest.py. For me, the selftest failed the first time since I added in some more libraries after the build, therefore I had to run `sudo python setup.py clean` and `sudo python setup.py build_ext -i` in order to fix it.  Source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/#pillow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[(I seem to be making a mess of things in the comments, sorry about that, here's a better version)

The error clearly states that you're missing `setuptools` for python3. The package `python3-setuptools` should take care of that (run `sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`).

Then, as you noticed, default `PIL` doesn't work for python3. [The current state of the github master of `Pillow`](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow) does, however. That will install by using `python3 setup.py build` and `sudo python3 setup.py install`.

Comment: Note that that release 1.7.8 is 4 months old, according to github. Can you try the current master (which worked for me)?

Comment: Missing `Python.h`, install the python development libraries; something like `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` (you might wanna google that).

Answer (score 1):

Your instructions are too long and not entirely scripted, these are better (same platform — recent Debian/Ubuntu):

```
sudo aptitude install python3-pip git
pip-3.2 install --user git+https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

for those here to get scipy working with PIL (Pillow), on python3

After executing the receipe Chin Ye above, I was then able to get scipy.misc.imread and scipy.misc.imsave to be available when issuing `import scipy.misc` by tweaking two lines in the file:

`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py`

in that file, replace the lines:

```
import Image
import ImageFilter
```

to be:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
```

---

the imports in `scipy.misc.__init__` then worked to allow the contents of `pilutil.py` to work (esp image io - from numpy array formats)

this was for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, `scipy.__version__ 0.9.0`

(for more information on the tweak itself, see  the docs for the Pillow implementaion of PIL)