# Install PIL/Pillow for ubuntu python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have successfully installed PIL/Pillow for python `3.4` but I want it for python `2.7`. I thought it might be automatically downloaded for `2.7` as well but when I tried the python shell from the terminal, it keeps saying `No module named PIL` and `No module named PILLOW`. What can I do? When I try all the installation commands as given in other answers, it says:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pillow in ./.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

My problem is the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002538/install-pil-in-ubuntu-12-04-python-2-7-and-python-3-2?rq=1)

Comment: How did you install it? I see two packages: `python-pil` and `python3-pil` in ubuntu repositories. Have you tried installing the former?

Answer (score 3):

Install PIL using `pip install pillow`

Then in the shell try `import PIL` or `from PIL import ...`

Comment: ImportError: No module named PIL

Comment: how did you installed PIL ?
Did you tried ? `pip install pillow`

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7 there is no module named PIL,
you can use PIL features through Pillow,so **PIL** aka **Pillow**
Your output shows you are still using python3
Switch to python 2.7 and try `pip install pillow`
Then you can directly import **PIL** and use its methods completely

Comment: How can I switch to python 2.7?

Comment: You have to change the python path which is already pointing to python 3.4 change that path to python 2.7 installed directory.then run python in CLI this  will automatically runs python 2.7(or)you can directly goto to python 2.7 package installed directory and run python.exe which start python 2.7 program

Comment: then what's the problem? you can edit PATH environment variable

Comment: How can I do this? Sorry, I'm a beginner and don't know what an environment variable is and how I can edit it

Comment: PATH=$PATH:<installed path>