# psycopg2 install for two versions of python

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a fresh debian install with :
+ default 2.6.6 python installed
+ also installed python3 at `/opt/python3/`
+ installed psycopg2

Problem :
`>>> import psycopg2`
works with standard `python`
but not the alternate python `/opt/python3/bin/python3`.
I presume it is an import path problem, but I don't know how to solve it being a newbie on python.

Comment: You should really use `virtualenv` to deal with multiple python version.

Comment: any tuto about `virutalenv` because I don't anything about them.

Comment: http://www.virtualenv.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `psycopg2` separately for your Python 3 installation.

You need to follow the [installation instructions for installing from source](http://pythonhosted.org/psycopg2/install.html#install-from-source), using `pip` or `easy_install` will be easiest (provided you have the `libpq-dev` debian package installed).

You *cannot* reuse the system-installed `psycopg2` because that'll only work on Python 2.

Comment: I did a separate install for psycopg2 though... from package rather then source. Does it make a difference ?

Comment: @MilleBii: Yes, if you installed the debian package then that will not be seen by or usable to the Python 3 installation.

Comment: Getting into trouble with installing `libpq-dev`...  with the following error `libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 8.4.13-0squeeze1) but 9.1.7-1~bpo60+1 is to be installed`. So I'm stuck.

Comment: @MilleBii: If you have a mix of Debian package versions you have a different problem, I'm afraid. To a certain extend using [apt pinning](http://www.argon.org/~roderick/apt-pinning.html) can help there. You could try and get un-stuck at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ perhaps.

Comment: used `-t squeeze-backports` on the apt-get command to get `libpq-dev` which worked... afterwards the `pip install psycopg2` fails

Comment: fails *how* exactly? are you using the correct `pip` command (one installed with your Python 3 setup)?

Comment: 1. created the `python3` virtualenv as suggested
2. apt-get install pip
3. apt-get -t squeeze-backports libpq-dev
4. pip install psycopg2

Comment: @MilleBii: The `apt-get install pip` command installs `pip` for your *system python only*. You need to install pip for the Python 3 installation.

Comment: getting compilation error the first one is : `In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @MilleBii: That's because it is compiling for the system python version (for which the headers need to be installed separately). Use tools that come with your Python 3 installation *only*.

Comment: I did activate python3 virtualenv though... so I thought the `apt-get pip` was going to install it on python3

Comment: @MilleBii: `apt-get` is not a python tool, it knows nothing about python virtualenv; it installs *only* for python versions that are themselves managed by `apt`. You need to install `pip` by hand; use [`get_pip.py`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/1.3.X/installing.html#using-get-pip) and run that with your python 3 binary.

Comment: got PIP installed at the right place. But `/opt/python3/bin/pip install psycopg2` still give the same results... now the very first log is `  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
`.  Looks like there is still an env. pb

Comment: I looked at the details in pip.log and there is an error in the gcc commands its taking the headers from the wrong python ie 2.6 and even at the wrong location. Where it should be `include/python3.3m` it uses `include/site/python6`

Comment: solution to install pip is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip). Then use `pip-3.3 install psycopg2`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and installing the python3 include files sorted the issue (while in the active virtualenv)

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev` as per solution provided in this post

[Psycopg2 fails to install on python 3 with pip issuing a fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650567/psycopg2-fails-to-install-on-python-3-with-pip-issuing-a-fatal-error)

Answer (score 0):

So I recap for the record and any one stumbing on this
1. Install virtualenv. [instructions here](http://www.virtualenv.org/)
2. Install pip for your version, in my case it was pip-3.3  [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip) in order to get `distribute_setup.py` and `get-pip.py`
3. enjoy  `> pip-3.3 install psycopg2`

Comment: I've done upgrading pip to `1.4.1` and installed pip-3.2, but still can't `pip-3.2 install psycopg2` with error: `./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`. Using Ubuntu 11.10.