# Psycopg2 fails to install on python 3 with pip issuing a fatal error

Tags: pip, fedora, python-3.3, psycopg2

```
$ yum install python3 postgresql python-devel libpqxx-devel
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Package python3-3.3.2-8.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package postgresql-9.3.2-2.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python-devel-2.7.5-9.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:libpqxx-devel-3.2-0.5.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I am trying to install [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/install/#installing-from-source-code) in my virtualenv to connect django with the postgresql database.

In Fedora 19 and postgresql-9.2 the path to pg_config was:

`/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin`

In Fedora 20, this directory does not exist.

However pg_config can be found in `/usr/bin/pg_config`.

Trying to install psycopg2:

```
 $ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin; pip install psycopg2
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.5.2.tar.gz (685kB): 685kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

... -compiling output here- ...

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.2 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090302 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/pgsql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.3/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement

In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:

./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/flyer/.virtualenvs/p3test/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/flyer/.virtualenvs/p3test/build/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mrsky4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/flyer/.virtualenvs/p3test/include/site/python3.3 failed with error code 1 in /home/flyer/.virtualenvs/p3test/build/psycopg2
Storing complete log in /home/flyer/.pip/pip.log
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have `python3-devel` installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing python3 include files

```
./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

you can probably find them in the `python3-devel` package.

Comment: for ubuntu this would be `python3-dev` . Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Install the python3-devel package to get it work

```
sudo dnf install python3-devel
```

If it works then alright or if it requires libpq-fe.h file then install it using the command:

```
sudo dnf install postgresql-devel
```

Comment: This is presumably a Fedora specific answer. Does it work on other distros?

Comment: The answer is specific to fedora and for other distros, there may be similar packages available, you can try installing them and check if it works or not.

Answer (score 2):

On **Ubuntu**. I solved this with:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the other answers this is caused by not having the right Python "devel" package installed. On CentOS, the Python "devel" rpm package is numbered with the with the qualified version. For example as of this writing the current versions are:

`python34-devel` for epel repository

`python36u-devel` for ius repository

Example Yum command (assumes [EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) is configured):

`sudo yum install python34-devel`

Related answer from server fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/710354/repository-for-python3-devel-on-centos-7