# How does the two version's Python work on ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am new to Linux and have just installed ubuntu12.10 on my laptop. I use Python and there are two version's Python on ubuntu, 2.7 and 3.2. And here comes my question, if I download a module and then setup it, which version will it be installed to? I don't know the command such as `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv` will install it to where, which version either. Is there a default version and then everything installed to it?

And when I want to use *pip* to install some packages, still I don't know which version it will match and I don't know how to install the package to the version I want. I have searched google and stackoverflow and know it has something to do with the *virtualenv*. And I read *virtualenv* document but I still don't understand it clearly.

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: I have found an answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip and I find if on ubuntu just use `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and then use pip-3.2 the package will be installed right.

Answer (score 2):

The [Debian Python Policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/) describes how packaged modules are supposed to interact with `dpkg` so that add-ons are installed, compiled etc for each installed version if Python.

IIRC the policy states that  `python` means `python2` and you have to use `python3` explicitly to get v3.

In practice, that means if you want to set up your own Python 3 environment with your own personal libraries, you will need a virtual environment (sort of like a vmware box or a chroot, except only for overriding the system-wide Python).

Answer (score 0):

You can check which python you're running by issuing the following command

```
which python
[output-path]eg: /opt/local/bin/python
```

Use this

```
/opt/local/bin/python --version
```

If this is the python version you want to pointing at Use this path in the topmost line of your python script. and use

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two(or more) binary python interpreters in /usr/bin/. Each python executable script you run(manage.py etc) specifies in the beginning something like this

```
    #!/usr/bin/python2.6
```

That are system level interpreters. They store their libraries in

```
    /usr/local/lib/pythonXX/site-packages
```

With virtualenv you are free to have your own sand boxed python environments. Each environment will have unix-like directory structure including

```
    $PATH_TO_ENV/lib/site-packages #library home
    $PATH_TO_ENV/bin               #binaries home
```

when you activate virtualenv, and then run any python script it will use python executable from $PATH_TO_ENV/bin. All libraries are set up into `$PATH_TO_ENV/lib/site-packages`  if you could remove `$PATH_TO_ENV` any time and do not worry about any garbage on system-level.

To set up virtualenvs I'm using something like this:

```
  sudo easy_install pip;
  sudo pip install virtualenv;
  sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper;

  echo "export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs" >> ~/.bashrc;
  echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc;
  . ~/.bashrc;
  mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME;
```

When using pip you could explicitly specify version number
ex.

```
  pip install django-debug-toolbar>=0.9.4,<1.0
```

if you are inside virtualenv package and all it's dependencies would be installed in

```
  $PATH_TO_ENV/lib/site-packages
```