# django uses python 2.6 instead of python 3.3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Hi I am using Mac OS (SnowLeopard). I have python installed by default which I guess is 2.6.
I installed python 3.3 from the python server and now installed django also. 
I created a django project using STARTPROJECT and tried to run it using manage.py runserver.

I get errors, but from the error its evident that the python getting used still is 2.6
How to change this?

The error is as

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x10169aed0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 21, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 127, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 97, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() keywords must be strings
```

Comment: How did you install Django?

Comment: Are you sure that pip is installed for python3.3, and that it is actually using python3?

Comment: @RolandSmith pip is installed for python2.6 I guess. How to change and install for python3.3?

Comment: See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3