# Installing python module for the right version of Python. Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, pygame

I need to install 'easypg' module for Python,

```
$ pip install easypg
```

does the job, but it installs the module for python2.7.
I have versions of python on my machine.
How do I specify installation for python3 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install  virtualenv for python3 Then try these commands:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 env-name
source env-name/bin/activate
pip install easypg
```

or

```
virtualenv-3.x  env-name
source env-name/bin/activate
pip install easypg
```