# cannot install networkx.*.*.egg package in python 3.3

Tags: networkx, egg

i am Nobe about python and its package,
I want to install networkx package for some graph calculation. I found it https://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx/1.8.1 . But the file is .egg.

Please help me to install that *.egg file for my python3.3 .
Thank you, in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [install docs](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/install.html) show you several ways to install `networkx`.  [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) is one of the easiest ways to get python packages installed (managing dependencies and updates etc).

On debian systems you can install pip by running:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

(note that there are [typically different packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12262143/1643946) for pip3 and for pip2)

and then you should be able to install networkx as follows:

```
sudo pip3 install networkx
```

If you use windows maybe read [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) to get started with pip.