# Installing Sci Kit Learn on Mac OSX

Tags: python, scikit-learn

On my OSX laptop I have installed Sci Kit Learn by copying and pasting this command `pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn` to terminal as instructed on [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#mac-osx) page.

This is the result I get when I run the command on terminal again:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages
Requirement already up-to-date: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

This is the error message I get when I run `from sklearn import datasets` on Python 3.3.4. IDLE: (I was trying [this](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#loading-an-example-dataset) example)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
from sklearn import dataset
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the packages installed for python 2.7 as you can see in the log

```
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and you're running with python 3.3.4.
So either run it with python 2.7.x or install the packages for python3.x. How? Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip-on-ubuntu)