# pip3.4 -V refers to python2.7 installation

Tags: python, pip

**Edit-rephrased question to be less misleading**

Is there a difference between pip3 and pip2?  `pip2 -V` and `pip3-V` both produce the output

pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

**Old question below**

I have seen recommendations to set up a python3 virtualenv using pip3, but when I type

```
pip3.4 -V
```

I get the output

```
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Which is exactly the same output I get from `pip -V` and `pip2 -V`.  My python3 installation works fine.  What's the deal?  Is pip, pip2, and pip3, actually the same thing?  Afterall https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/index.html, only mentions pip.  Furthermore strangely, in my `/usr/bin` folder, I can see my pip3 is older than my pip3.4 binary -- which explains why `pip3 -V` fails with

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.6
```

So what is the deal?  is the pip3 syntax redundant, or is there something wrong with my system? I use opensuse 13.2

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip-on-ubuntu. it might help. you can specify which python to use in your virtualenv. Pip then gets automatically installed for that version inside the environnement

Answer (score 12):

In Debian, I found three short files in /usr/local/bin: pip; pip3; and pip3.4. All were identical:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

By changing the very first shebang line of pip3 (with sudo) to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Then ensuring that the original pip was explicitly

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
```

All of my similar confusion and errors disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with the same issue on my EC2 and finally found the solution to it. You can use it in following way-

```
python3 -m pip <install> <library>
```

adding python3 -m before pip calls pip3 from the correct location. You can check its location as follows-

```
python3 -m pip -V
pip 19.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Answer (score 1):

After reinstalling  `python3-pip` (opensuse package) `pip3 -V` and `pip3.4 -V` produce correct output

```
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

I had actually also uninstalled pip2 in the process and strangely reinstalling pip2 with `python get-pip` ([get-pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)) changed my newly working pip3.4 to point to the python2 site-packages again.  This I just changed by deleting the wrong pip3.4 and making a symlink to pip3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--python=python3` flag to specify the Python version you want to use.

Comment: command: `pip --python=python3 install -r requirements.txt`
output: `no such option: --python`

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same problem, the following aliasing helped.

alias pip3="python3 -m pip"