# Python: Installed a local package with pip3, but got module not found error

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Procedure:

- I strictly followed the instructions here:  https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html
- Except that I used the `pip3 install -e .`

Error:

It still can not find the module:

```
python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 25 2018, 14:26:36)
import funniest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'funniest'
```

However, when I import the module in `python`, it CAN find it:

```
python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)
import funniest
```

My python:

```
sys.executable
'/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6'
```

**Question**

Why `pip3` installed it for python 2.7 not for my python 3.x ?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `pip3 --version` return?

Comment: It returns: ```pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)``` But why?

Comment: Looks like a wrong symlink - what does `ls $(which pip3)` return?

Comment: ```> ls $(which pip3)
/usr/local/bin/pip3*``` Some week ago I used ```brew``` for an upgrade (not sure if it is python), then it messed my python up, I guess.

Comment: Hi @hoefling, seems that I need to change the shebang line, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407208/pip3-4-v-refers-to-python2-7-installation

Answer (score 13):

Following the hint from @hoefling, I found that my pip3 is somewhat linked to a wrong python version.

Then install with `python3 -m pip install` worked.

Comment: Don't forget to add the module you want to install at the end: `python3 -m pip install module-name`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you use a virtual environment, to get around all this hassle.

If you make a virtual environment with python3, there is no ambiguity of python versions, and life is much simpler.

Use the command

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

and then, depending on where your python3 is residing (you can check by typing `which python3` on the terminal), you should do something like this next:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 mypy3
source mypy3/bin/activate
```

your terminal will show `(mypy3)` in the beginning of the line (before the prompt) at this point. Here, you can do:

```
pip install funniest
```

Another way is to use `virtualenvwrapper` , which I find very convenient.

Look at the [documentation](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or the relevant parts of [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) tutorial if you wish to know more. But make sure you create an environment with python3 alone, so that there is no confusion.