# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zope.deprecation'

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, ubuntu-18.04

Okay, I have lost a day in debugging the script and now I don't have any other option to post a question on StackOverflow. I have a python script which installs Apache Airflow on the machine using a `requirement.txt` file nothing rocket science simply

```
sudo pip3 install -r requirement.txt
```

The problem is during installation I am getting an exception

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zope.deprecation'

at a line which is trying to execute following statement

```
from airflow.models.variable import Variable
```

The script has three stages

First: It updates the OS using somewhat `apt-get update` and also installs some system libraries

Second: It invokes `airflow initdb` etc

Third: It actually tries to create some specific entries in airflow meta-database, and Its here in this stage I am invoking the statement `from airflow.models.variable import Variable` which throws an exception

I install all dependencies in stage First so the **Module**  `zope.deprecation` is also installed via `requirement.txt` file. The module is there in `site-packages` folder but It doesn't get imported and throws an exception

I know there are already 7700+ question with title ModuleNotFoundError on StackOverflow and I don't declare that I checked out them all but I did my homework and tried various solutions but none are working for me, Few links I checked out are below

[adding directory to sys.path /PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath)

[Unable to import a module that is definitely installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)

[Python: Installed a local package with pip3, but got module not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643068/python-installed-a-local-package-with-pip3-but-got-module-not-found-error)

I can't share the code because of policy issues, but I hope you guys understand.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Shahbaz Ali - Were you able to fix this problem? I'm facing this very same issue.

Answer (score 0):

there is a error by zope and zope.deprecation.
you can do this:

> pip uninstall zope
>
> pip uninstall zope.deprecation

and then:

> pip install zope.deprecation