# pip3 is not installing packages for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When I run my python script using python3, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "rea_scrape.py", line 2, in
>   
>       import requests ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

When I run `pip3 install requests` it's apparent that requests has been installed.

> Requirement already satisfied: requests in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (2.18.4) Requirement already
>   satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
>   (from requests) (2018.4.16) Requirement already satisfied:
>   chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from
>   requests) (3.0.4) Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests) (2.6) Requirement
>   already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests) (1.22)

However, closer inspection of the messages seem to indicate that pip3 is installing packages for Python2.7, which is not my intention.

The result is that nothing I install using the `pip3` command can be imported into a script run by `python3`.

How do I fix this?

FYI I'm using MacOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it looks like your pip3 installation is pointing to the wrong version of python. If you look at the file inside your `/usr/local/bin` there you can see a file called pip3. Where you can see which version of python it's been pointing. In my case, the file has the content something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

In you case the first line must be `#!usr/bin/python2` . You can varify that by using `pip3 -V` on your terminal.

The other way to fix this would be to completely uninstall your pip3 installation and again re-installing `python3-pip`

2. curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
3. python3
   From this answer: [How to install pip for Python 3 on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082935/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-on-mac-os-x)

Also please look at this question: [pip3.4 -V refers to python2.7 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407208/pip3-4-v-refers-to-python2-7-installation)
This question should answer you fully.