# Unable to compile python with pyglet in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyglet

In Ubuntu 15.10,Running

```
python3.4 sound.py
```

leads to this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sound.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyglet
ImportError: No module named 'pyglet'
```

I already installed pyglet with running this command:

```
sudo easy_install -U pyglet
```

resulting

```
Searching for pyglet
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyglet/
Best match: pyglet 1.2.4
Processing pyglet-1.2.4-py2.7.egg
pyglet 1.2.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.2.4-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pyglet
Finished processing dependencies for pyglet
```

I am confused about what is missing. I guess there are some confusion about different verions of python, pyglet or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the install output it seems that the installed version of pyglet goes to **python 2.7 packages**. From your command you are explicitly calling **python 3.4** There might be a problem there. python 3.4 will not go to 2.7's packages to check for the module.

I suggest that you call the script using **python 2.7**. running just python is enough (the default env python)

You can take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip-on-ubuntu) on the installation of python 2 and 3 packages too