# pandas module and Python 3 in OSX

Tags: python, macos, pandas, python-3.5

I'm trying to make pandas module (that I've install through pip) working with Python 3.5.
When I'm doing `import pandas` in Python 2.7 everything is fine, but I get the following error with 3.5 version:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Any idea why it's not working ? Thanks.

Comment: You installed it for Python 2.7 *only*. See here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip-on-ubuntu

Comment: I'm checking it, but I'm on OSX

Comment: Same concept, there are other similar questions too - here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions

Answer (score 0):

In python, modules are installed in different virtual environment. So you need to activate the corresponding virtual environment and install, in termial:

```
source activate python3  # your virtual environment name for python 3.
pip install pandas
```