# Can I Install a Python Package for 34 and not for 27?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I ran: 'pip install uncertainties' and it went into Python27, but I need to run this from Python34.  Now, I can't seem to uninstall it from 27.  That seems to be the default and it keeps going back to that when I try to install uncertainties.

In Environment Variable I only have this in the Path: 'C:\Python34\Scripts'

I don't know why it keeps defaulting to Python27.  Is there a way to change this, or control it?

I read all comments, and took a look at those other resources.  Now I am editing my OP to explain my findings (I can add this to the Comments section).

I got virtualenv to install just fine.  However, I still can't get any traction with this thing.

C:>pip3.4 install uncertainties
'pip3.4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:>pip34 install uncertainties
'pip34' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:>py -3.4 -m pip install uncertainties
C:\Python34\python.exe: No module named pip

C:>python3 -m pip install uncertainties
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:>python34 -m pip install uncertainties
'python34' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:>python3.4 -m pip install uncertainties
'python3.4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `pip3 install uncertainties`

Comment: Would recommend reading up on `virtualenv` http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/.

Comment: here is another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). Its purpose is exactly that: keep different python interpreters and their libraries correctly installed and isolated from one another.

Comment: I will include python3 installation directory in path variable so `python3` commands becomes available to system. Then simply do python3 pip install <your-module>

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and got this result: python3 is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.