# How to install python3-dev in Oracle Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

How can I install python3-dev in Oracle Linux?

`yum install python3-dev` is not working.

It gives a message:

> No package python3-dev available.

I need python3-dev to convert a python script to Linux executable using Cython.

I tried to search rpm files, that also did not work.

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

friend, OL6 and OL7 repo havent python 3, only 2

[image: OL7 official repo]
[image: OL6 official repo]

then:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
xz -d Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
tar -xvf Python-3.6.5.tar
cd Python-3.6.5
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

if no step goes wrong, take a coffe, wait about 10 minutes in make test phase and be happy.

Comment: This one worked for Oracle Linux 7.3.

Answer (score 4):

**The hard way is with the following statements:**

**Note** I used oraclelinux:7-slim docker container

```
yum -y install wget \
    && yum -y install gcc readline readline-devel \
    && yum -y install zlib zlib-devel \
    && yum -y install libffi-devel openssl-devel \
    && yum -y install tar gzip \
    && yum -y install make \
    && yum clean all

  wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.5/Python-3.7.5.tgz \
     && tar -xf Python-3.7.5.tgz \
     && cd Python-3.7.5 \
     && ./configure --enable-optimizations \
     && make \
     && make test
     && make install
```

**And the easy way is:**

```
yum update \
&& yum -y install python3
```

Answer (score 3):

When I stumbled into the same problem the links provided in the other answers didn't work and I didn't want to work out dependencies to install from source.

An easy way to install Python3.6 on Oracle Linux that I found is described in [this blog](https://geraldonit.com/2019/01/08/how-to-install-python-3-on-oracle-linux/). Here are the three easy steps:

```
sudo yum install -y yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --enable *EPEL
sudo yum install -y python36
```

I've tested it to work on the `7-slim` tag of the official [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/oraclelinux). Naturally, there I had to drop the `sudo` prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use RPMs from Oracle Linux, you can install Python 3 via Software Collections.

Check the Oracle documentation on how to enable Software Collections on your Oracle Linux server and then install Python 3: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E59096/html/index.html