# Where are raspberryPi python packages installed?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I was given a raspberry pifor my birthday and decided to make an alarm clock out of one. I wrote all the code on my PC, works completely fine and expected but I'm having slight issues with installing packages on the raspberry pi.

When I open the terminal, I'm in the directory "home/pi".

I then run the command

```
sudo easy_install -U schedule
```

which installs fine, I then try to run my code which is stored in "home/pi", but get an error on:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/LED.py", line 1, in <module>
import schedule
ImportError: No module named 'schedule'
```

any tips? I've also installed schedule via pip in the same directory - pip install schedule which installs perfectly fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import schedule
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(5)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Im not experienced with RasPi, but as far as i know, `pip` will do the trick!

Comment: @I.Renk, this is my issue, i've tried pip install schedule and it's still throwing that error :(

Comment: Can u post related code to your issue?

Comment: it is in Usr/bin/ . just give a try to import module from there , Do you have this line added on top of you program #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: Which python version? You might have python2 and 3 installed. You might have installed it for the other  python version

Comment: @IronFist code is added atm, i'm still porting the code over so schedule isnt actually used other than an import

Comment: Try : `$pip3 install schedule ` you might be running Python3 but you installed `schedule` for python2

Comment: @IronFist ah you life saver! it works! add that as a answer and ill mark it asap :)

Comment: @RaspberryCeri, Glad you fixed it, actually no need for that, this was a common problem which I faced personally. Enjoy your time with the Pi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install python3 version of package via pip on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4):

Python searches the packages in all directories in the [python path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

For instance, these directories for me are :

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

Note that the first path is "*the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter*", often the current directory when you run your python script.

Also note that pip should install the packages in the `site-packages` directory. (The last path in my `sys.path` in my previous example). There should be one of these directory per python installation.

A simple command line like `find / -name site-packages` should be enough to find them all. But keep in mind that not all python interpreter will use the same `sys.path` : obviously, if you install some package for python2, you won't be able to access it from a python3 interpreter. Same thing if you use [virtualenvs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 1):

just ran into the same problem and on my raspberry 4 it helped when I used the following from the command line where the python script was launched:
sudo python3 example.py
Note the "3" at the end of "python" above.

Answer (score 0):

i came across this when searching for an answer. and then i was just testing something that got me thinking about where the packages.
i have had probles using "sudo python something.py".
getting the "ImportError: No module named "some module"

i have always been using "pip install" or "pip3 install", and always could have used it as my user, but been as i wrote, problem when i "sudo python something.py"

what fixed it in my case, is install the module again with "sudo pip install" or sudo pip3 install". though then the modules would be installed 2 places i guess. though i havent tested how it would be reachable for a normal user yet...