# How to use python2 modules in python3 in linux server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

python 2.7 is installed at `/usr/lib`
packages are installed at `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
python 3 is installed at `/usr/local/bin`

```
python3 command is not able to fetch the packages/modules from the above mentioned directory.
```

$PATH looks like

```
[PATH][1]
```

How can i fetch or use those packages in python3 .

Comment: You need to install the module for Python3... Python2 modules are written for Python2 and won't work in 3. Simply use `pip3 instead of pip` to install required module.

Comment: `python3 -m pip --user install some-packages`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install python3 version of package via pip on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @Mick_ pip3 is not installed in Python3. How to do that ?

Comment: Run Python installer again and pay attention to each step ... there is tick box for pip.