# not able to install pip on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, pip

When I typed:

```
python get-pip.py
 Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
 Collecting wheel
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/30/e935244ca6165187ae8be876b6316ae201b71485538ffac1d718843025a9/wheel-0.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
 Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 18.0
    Uninstalling pip-18.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-18.0
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
```

It is showing error:

```
 Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip'
 Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

What should I do?

Comment: I'm sure there is an answer to this already. You basically need to use a virtualenv, or sudo when installing packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install python3 version of package via pip on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a permissions error. You might need root to install pip, if the directories the installer is trying to access are owned by root. For security reasons, I recommend against installing it/running it with sudo, if you're trying to go that route.

Related: [pip install -r: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)