# How to solve cannot import name 'ModuleName' error?

Tags: python, path, importerror, ubuntu-18.04

I just started to use Python ASE module for research. When I work on the shell this module works perfectly but when I try to use it on idle it gives an error. I don't know how to solve this problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. Both Python3.6 and 2.7 are installed. I'm using Python3.6 for both shell and idle. For a better understanding I'm writing what I got:

```
from ase import Atoms



Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/birkan/Desktop/archive/Python/ase.py", line 1, in <module>
   from ase import Atoms
 File "/home/birkan/Desktop/archive/Python/ase.py", line 1, in <module>
   from ase import Atoms
 ImportError: cannot import name 'Atoms'
 [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
 [cmd: ['/usr/bin/python3.6', '/home/birkan/Desktop/archive/Python   /ase.py']]
 [dir: /home/birkan/Desktop/archive/Python]
 [path: /home/birkan/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr /sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Hey! I just edited

Comment: You named your file `ase.py`. This clashes with the name of the module you are trying to import from.

Comment: Not really. It gives the same error with different name as well.

Comment: Did you remove the original file?

Comment: Yes, if you mean ase.py

Comment: Open an interactive interpreter in the folder where you run your code from, type `import ase`, then `ase` and post the printed line.

Comment: Here it is:                                                                                      birkan@birkan:~/Desktop/archive/Python$ import ase
ase
import-im6.q16: not authorized `ase' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
birkan@birkan:~/Desktop/archive/Python$ ase
usage: ase [-h] [--version] [-T]
           {help,info,test,gui,db,run,band-structure,build,eos,ulm,find,nomad-upload,nomad-get,convert,reciprocal,completion}

Comment: Run it in the interactive Python interpreter, not the shell. Hint: run `python`!

Comment: I did it. It also gives same error.

Comment: Does your prompt look like `>>> `?

Comment: No. I did not open the shell. It already works with shell

Answer (score 0):

Please check how you installed ASE module, if your default python version is python2.7 and you simply installed it by using `"pip install ase"` then your ASE module is installed against version 2.7 which I guess does not support ASE as it is supported from 3.5 upwards. 
Python3 Version of packages would be a little differently installed, either use pip3 if it is available or try the other options like virtualenv and some other ideas from here:

[How to install python3 version of package via pip on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip-on-ubuntu)