# No module named "yaml"

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have installed pyyaml by using `pip install pyyaml` on my mac, but I can't seem to use the module after installation, due to

> ImportError: No module named 'yaml'

Version `PyYAML-5.1.2`

The Python version is `3.7`.

I can't seem to understand why this happens. Can anyone shed some light on the matter?

Comment: Do you also have Python 2.7.x installed on your system? In that case your `pip install` might have installed it for that version instead of Python 3.x. Do you have a `pip3` command as well?

Comment: have you tried "python3 -m pip install pyyaml"?

Comment: Yes I do have python 2.7.x in my system, but currently the default python version is 3.7. And I tried using the command  "python3 -m pip install pyyaml", still the same...

Answer (score 3):

Try `pip3.x install pyyaml` where the `3.x` corresponds to what version of Python you are using. For example I use `pip3.6`.

This is what worked for me, [although you can look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip-on-ubuntu) for more options.