# Install numpy on python3.3 - Install pip for python3

Tags: numpy, python-3.x

For python 3.2 I used `sudo apt-get install python3.2-numpy`.It worked.
What to do for python3.3? Nothing I could think of works. Same goes for scipy, etc.
Thanks.

Edit: this is how it looks like

```
radu@sunlit-inspired:~$ python3
Python 3.3.2 (default, Jul  3 2013, 10:17:40) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: What did you do and what errors did you get?

Comment: Install python3.3: http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-python-3-3-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-and-12-04/ . Once you have it, follow @LennartRegebro answer.

Comment: @Zhneya: do you mean I should uninstall and install anew using deadsnakes?

Answer (score 43):

In the solution below I used `python3.4` as binary, but it's safe to use with any version or binary of python. it works fine on windows too (except the downloading "get-pip.py" with `wget` obviously but just save the file locally and run it with python, see below).

This is great if you have multiple versions of python installed, so you can manage external libraries per python version.

So first, I'd recommend `get-pip.py`, it's great to install pip:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

Then you need to install pip for your version of python, I have `python3.4` so for me this is the command:

```
python3.4 get-pip.py
```

Now pip is installed for this version and I'll use pip "contextualized" to that version this way:

```
python3.4 -m pip
```

So to install numpy for python3.4 I'll use :

```
python3.4 -m pip install numpy
```

Note that `numpy` is quite the heavy library. I thought my system was hanging and failing.
But using the verbose option, you can see that the system is fine :

```
python3.4 -m pip install numpy -v
```

> This may tell you that you lack **python.h** but you can easily get python headers:
>
> *Of course you want to keep using your python version in those commands*
>
> On **Debian**-like (Debian, Ubuntu, Kali, ...) :
>
> ```
> apt-get install python34-dev
> ```
>
> On **RHEL** (Red hat, CentOS, Fedora) it would be something like this:
>
> ```
> yum install python34-devel
> ```
>
> or more recently
>
> ```
> dnf install python34-devel
> ```
>
> If that doesn't work for you, there's a great topic with more coverage: [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)
>
> **Finally**, once you've got python header files you can just rerun the pip install command:
>
> ```
> python3.4 -m pip install numpy -v
> ```

Comment: this works great, especially on my computer where I have both 2.7 and 3.x

Comment: you need some commands to run as sudo user otherwise this answer helped.

Comment: python34-devel is not found wehn using yum search python34-devel

Comment: @jerseybean you may lack `epel-release` package

Answer (score 14):

From the terminal run:

```
  sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

This package contains Numpy for Python 3.

For scipy:

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
```

For for plotting graphs use  pylab:

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy` worked for me :)

Answer (score 11):

The normal way to install Python libraries is with [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/). Your way of installing it for Python 3.2 works because it's the system Python, and that's the way to install things for system-provided Pythons on Debian-based systems.

If your Python 3.3 is system-provided, you should probably use a similar command. Otherwise you should probably use pip.

I took my Python 3.3 installation, created a virtualenv and run pip install in it, and that seems to have worked as expected:

```
$ virtualenv-3.3 testenv
$ cd testenv
$ bin/pip install numpy
blablabl

$ bin/python3
Python 3.3.2 (default, Jun 17 2013, 17:49:21) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

Comment: unfortunately my system Python is 2.7.3 so pip installs there. there is a pip-3.2 but no pip-3.3.

Comment: @Radu: Just like numpy needs to be installed specifically for Python 3.3, pip needs to be installed for Python 3.3. http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/newbie-hint-on-installing-python-and-its-modules-and-packages/

Comment: i ran `python3 distribute_setup.py` and it tells me `Installing easy_install-3.2 script to /usr/local/bin` ! i can confirm that python3 is python3.3 not python3.2.

Comment: @Radu: I find it somewhat hard to believe that distribute_setup.py would create an easy_install-3.2 if executed with Python 3.3. If it really does, your installs are seriously messed up.

Comment: I believe you. Yet this is what happens. Could you be so kind and tell me what would you do if you had this situation on your machine and you needed python3.3? Thank you.

Comment: @Radu: Uninstall all versions of Python 3 and reinstall them correctly. Read http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/newbie-hint-on-installing-python-and-its-modules-and-packages/ first. Perhaps Zhenyas link to the deadnakes distro is an option as well.

Comment: You have to activate the virtualenv before using pip and python: `source testenv/bin/activate`

Comment: pip works properly within a 32-bit Python installation  (V 3.6.1) on a Windows 7 (64 bit)

Answer (score 5):

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04. This seemed to work:

```
$ sudo pip3 install numpy
```

On RHEL this worked:

```
$ sudo python3 -m pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 4):

My issue was the failure to import numpy into my python files. I was receiving the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'". I ran into the same issue and I was not referencing python3 on the installation of numpy. I inputted the following into my terminal for OSX and my problems were solved:

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

On fedora/rhel/centos you need to

```
sudo yum install -y python3-devel
```

before

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.3 test-3.3
pip install numpy
```

otherwise you'll get

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```