# Error message when install reportlab and PIL using by pip

Tags: python, pip, reportlab

I working on install indico. But came up some issue when i use pip.

When i run this command

`pip install reportlab PIL`

i got this output and i don't understand problem..

```
Downloading/unpacking reportlab
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/setup.py) egg_info for package reportlab
    ################################################
    #Attempting install of _rl_accel & pyHnj
    #extensions from '/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel'
    ################################################
    ################################################
    #Attempting install of _renderPM
    #extensions from '/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM'
    will use package libart 2.3.12
    # installing without freetype no ttf, sorry!
    # You need to install a static library version of the freetype2 software
    # If you need truetype support in renderPM
    # You may need to edit setup.cfg (win32)
    # or edit this file to access the library if it is installed
    ################################################
    Downloading standard T1 font curves
    Finished download of standard T1 font curves

    ()
    ########## SUMMARY INFO #########
    ################################################
    #Attempting install of _rl_accel & pyHnj
    #extensions from '/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel'
    ################################################
    ################################################
    #Attempting install of _renderPM
    #extensions from '/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM'
    will use package libart 2.3.12
    # installing without freetype no ttf, sorry!
    # You need to install a static library version of the freetype2 software
    # If you need truetype support in renderPM
    # You may need to edit setup.cfg (win32)
    # or edit this file to access the library if it is installed
    ################################################
    Downloading standard T1 font curves
    Finished download of standard T1 font curves
Downloading/unpacking pillow==2.0.0,>=2.4.0 (from reportlab)
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package pillow

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pip>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (from reportlab)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-4.0.1-py2.7.egg (from reportlab)
Installing collected packages: reportlab, pillow
  Running setup.py install for reportlab
    ################################################
    #Attempting install of _rl_accel & pyHnj
    #extensions from '/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel'
    ################################################
    ################################################
    #Attempting install of _renderPM
    #extensions from '/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM'
    will use package libart 2.3.12
    # installing without freetype no ttf, sorry!
    # You need to install a static library version of the freetype2 software
    # If you need truetype support in renderPM
    # You may need to edit setup.cfg (win32)
    # or edit this file to access the library if it is installed
    ################################################
    Standard T1 font curves already downloaded
    building 'reportlab.lib._rl_accel' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c /tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.o
    /tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c:8:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-MLzgND-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ################################################

#Attempting install of _rl_accel & pyHnj

#extensions from '/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel'

################################################

################################################

#Attempting install of _renderPM

#extensions from '/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM'

will use package libart 2.3.12

# installing without freetype no ttf, sorry!

# You need to install a static library version of the freetype2 software

# If you need truetype support in renderPM

# You may need to edit setup.cfg (win32)

# or edit this file to access the library if it is installed

################################################

Standard T1 font curves already downloaded

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab

copying src/reportlab/rl_settings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab

copying src/reportlab/rl_config.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab

copying src/reportlab/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/linecharts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/utils3d.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/areas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/textlabels.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/spider.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/axes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/markers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/dotbox.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/slidebox.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/doughnut.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/piecharts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/legends.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/lineplots.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/barcharts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/excelcolors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/bubble.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/stacked_bar.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/line_chart.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/scatter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/exploded_pie.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/stacked_column.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/scatter_lines_markers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/runall.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/linechart_with_markers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/clustered_column.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/filled_radar.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/clustered_bar.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/radar.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/scatter_lines.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

copying src/reportlab/graphics/samples/simple_pie.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/samples

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/widgets

copying src/reportlab/graphics/widgets/eventcal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/widgets

copying src/reportlab/graphics/widgets/signsandsymbols.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/widgets

copying src/reportlab/graphics/widgets/flags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/widgets

copying src/reportlab/graphics/widgets/grids.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/widgets

copying src/reportlab/graphics/widgets/markers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/widgets

copying src/reportlab/graphics/widgets/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/widgets

copying src/reportlab/graphics/widgets/table.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/widgets

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/qr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/widgets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/lto.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/code39.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/code128.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/code93.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/fourstate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/usps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/usps4s.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/eanbc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/barcode

copying src/reportlab/graphics/testshapes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics

copying src/reportlab/graphics/renderPM.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics

copying src/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics

copying src/reportlab/graphics/widgetbase.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics

copying src/reportlab/graphics/testdrawings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics

copying src/reportlab/graphics/renderPS.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics

copying src/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics

copying src/reportlab/graphics/renderSVG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics

copying src/reportlab/graphics/shapes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics

copying src/reportlab/graphics/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/PyFontify.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/rltempfile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/set_ops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/formatters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/normalDate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/boxstuff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/yaml.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/rl_accel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/arciv.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/abag.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/rparsexml.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/fontfinder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/geomutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/corp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/textsplit.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/units.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/enums.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/validators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/sequencer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/colors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/styles.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/attrmap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/extformat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/randomtext.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/pdfencrypt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/pygments2xpre.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/logger.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/fonts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/pagesizes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

copying src/reportlab/lib/codecharts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_zapfdingbats.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_courierbold.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_pdfdoc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_zapfdingbats.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/rl_codecs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_courieroblique.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_helveticabold.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfpattern.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_timesroman.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_symbol.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_cidfontdata.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_symbol.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_timesitalic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_helveticaboldoblique.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/cidfonts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_macroman.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_helveticaoblique.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfmetrics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_courierboldoblique.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_courier.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_standard.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_can_cmap_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_helvetica.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_macexpert.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_timesbolditalic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_winansi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_timesbold.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfbase

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfgen

copying src/reportlab/pdfgen/pdfimages.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfgen

copying src/reportlab/pdfgen/canvas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfgen

copying src/reportlab/pdfgen/textobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfgen

copying src/reportlab/pdfgen/pdfgeom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfgen

copying src/reportlab/pdfgen/pathobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfgen

copying src/reportlab/pdfgen/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/pdfgen

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

copying src/reportlab/platypus/xpreformatted.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

copying src/reportlab/platypus/frames.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

copying src/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

copying src/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

copying src/reportlab/platypus/tables.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

copying src/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

copying src/reportlab/platypus/tableofcontents.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

copying src/reportlab/platypus/paragraph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

copying src/reportlab/platypus/figures.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

copying src/reportlab/platypus/para.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

copying src/reportlab/platypus/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/platypus

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/00readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/bitstream-vera-license.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/DarkGarden-copying-gpl.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/DarkGarden-copying.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/DarkGarden-readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/DarkGarden.sfd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/DarkGardenMK.afm -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/DarkGardenMK.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/Vera.ttf -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/VeraBd.ttf -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/VeraBI.ttf -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/VeraIt.ttf -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/_abi____.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/_ab_____.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/_ai_____.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/_a______.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/cobo____.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/cob_____.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/com_____.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/coo_____.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/_ebi____.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/_eb_____.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/_ei_____.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/_er_____.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/sy______.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/zd______.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/zx______.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/fonts/zy______.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts

copying src/reportlab/lib/hyphen.mashed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib

running build_ext

building 'reportlab.lib._rl_accel' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_root

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c /tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.o

/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c:8:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-MLzgND-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/reportlab

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Im using pip first time. I didnt understand what is the problem.

Comment: Why Do you think you have a problem? did the install fail? doesn't look like that..

Comment: @alonisser "fatal error" is a good hint that something has failed. You need the python headers, as seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)