# Installing pycrypto on raspbian for python 3.2.3

Tags: python, raspbian, pycrypto

Im trying to crate a `cryptosystem` on the `raspbian` OS. Chose python and pycrypto because the OS comes with python 3.2.3 pre-installed. Moved the "`pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz`" to the folder where python files are located and extracted there. Suposed to build using the command "`python setup.py build`" and then install.

But during the build phase, keep getting the error:

```
"pi@raspberrypi /usr/lib/python3.2/pycrypto-2.6.1 $ python setup.py buildrunning build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_configure
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-2.7/src/MD2.o
src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

"
```

Not able to figure out whether I am supposed to change the pathing. Could somebody give an insight in to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.

The `libgmp-dev` package provides the necessary files to support building the optimized module here:

```
apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

> src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

If you search for `fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`, the very first Google result is for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory) StackOverflow question, which tells you that you need to install the `python-dev` package:

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

In general, if you are building software from source you will need the corresponding `-dev` package for any required libraries; these packages provide header files (`foo.h`) and the unversioned shared libraries necessary for linking.

Comment: Followed your directions, I have it installed. Thank you so much. It makes more sense than when I began.

Comment: i have installed libgmp-dev. Below I've shown the instance were the update i successful. But the build command for pycrypto still fails on a GMP or MPIR fail.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgmp-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install python-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cd /usr/lib/python3.2/pycrypto-2.6.1/
pi@raspberrypi /usr/lib/python3.2/pycrypto-2.6.1 $ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_configure
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.