# makecython++ causes fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory despite python3-dev installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, cython, python-c-api, python-c-extension

My makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

.PHONY: all
all:
    pip install runcython
    makecython++ stitch_wrapper.pyx "" "stitch_rects.cpp ./hungarian/hungarian.cpp"

hungarian: hungarian/hungarian.so

hungarian/hungarian.so:
    cd hungarian && \
    TF_INC=$$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())') && \
    if [ `uname` == Darwin ];\
    then g++ -std=c++11 -shared hungarian.cc -o hungarian.so -fPIC -I $$TF_INC -undefined dynamic_lookup;\
    else g++ -std=c++11 -shared hungarian.cc -o hungarian.so -fPIC -I  $$TF_INC; fi
```

I have already installed

```
-cython
-runcython
-python-dev
-python3-dev
-cffi
```

Unfortunately I continue to get the error:

```
pkg-config: command not found
.cpp:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21530866/4657412. You need to specify the path in the make file. I believe Python.h is not automatically on the include path to help multiple versions not conflict

Comment: @Dawon I have added flag `-I/usr/include/python3.5 -lpython3.5` after `makecython++`command line with no success and get the error `makecython++ requires a *.pyx file.
` seems that flag syntax isn't correct for makecython++

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `makecython++` so I'm guessing a bit, but I think you want to send those flags to g++ rather than `makecython++`

Comment: @DavidW in my case I have to use makecython++ not gcc. How I should  add \-I/usr/include/python3.5\ to path?

Comment: Sorry - don't know. Looking at the source https://github.com/Russell91/runcython/blob/master/makecython%2B%2B it looks like it tries to do this (the `pkg-config` part) but I wonder if it does it for Python2 rather than Python3. I have no really idea how to fix it though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you already have

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython3-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython3.4-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython3.5-dev
```

the problem may be related to missing of one of these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install Cython
sudo apt-get install pkgconf
sudo apt-get install libpkgconf
sudo apt-get install python-pkgconfig
sudo apt-get install python3-pkgconfig
```

Comment: apt-get install libpython3.7-dev - solved "Python.h: No such file or directory" with python 3.7