# How to install Kivy on Solus distro?

Tags: python, kivy, solus

I'm not using Ubuntu (I'm on Solus), so I can't do the PPA. I've followed all the install guides I can find for manual installation but none seem to be working.

I get the error:

```
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
/tmp/pip-build-utw792cs/kivy/kivy/graphics/scissor_instructions.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include "Python.h"

                         ^
   compilation terminated.

  error: command 'x86_64-solus-linux-gcc' failed with exit status 1

\----------------------------------------  
Command "/usr/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;\__file__='/tmp/pip-build-utw792cs/kivy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(\__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, \__file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-rvj0_9sh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-utw792cs/kivy/
```

I've searched around for install guides but they all end with the same error at some point. Does anyone know how to install Kivy because it seems like a really cool tool.

Comment: it means your python is not properly installed, see the thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: What distribution *are* you using, then?

Comment: @RolandSmith Solus currently, sorry. I forgot to add that in.

Comment: @JanSila That seems to have done something! Now I get suck here: https://pastebin.com/aDcXLh95

Comment: *In general*, I would advise you to use the package system that your distribution provides, rather than doing everything by yourself.

Comment: @RolandSmith Currently Solus doesn't provide a package for Kivy so I've got to.

Comment: @crabcrabcam Then I would suggest trying to use the available infrastructure and build a Solus package. In general such package building tools have solutions in place for expressing dependencies and adding the correct compiler flags et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install kivy
```

Assuming you already installed `pip` and other dependencies like `mesalib-devel`