# Pyconcrete setup.py install Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having an issue with the pyconcrete installation from source,

```
src/pyconcrete_ext/pyconcrete.c:18:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or 
directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am running it how the github readme tells me to, 
which is python setup.py install

I Use the default passphrase, 
and get the same error every time.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: How do i fix such dupilcate?

Comment: The linked answer suggests you haven't yet installed the header files and static libraries for python dev. And can install them using your distribution's package manager, see suggested command in the link

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Comment: I was still unable to fix it.

Comment: what distro of linux are you using?

Comment: Windows. But i have tried it on ubuntu 14-16

Comment: Okay I think that is the problem - the solution will be different on Windows than on Ubuntu. On your windows machine, install [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) and then try compiling/installing `pyconcrete` again

Comment: I have the Visual C++ Compiler for Py27 on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

For [pyconcrete](https://github.com/Falldog/pyconcrete) support on windows, please pull the latest code.

Follow the below steps

- Install VisualStudio 2008 or [MSVC for Python2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)
- Open VS2008 Command Prompt
- `set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1`
- `set SET MSSdk=1`
- create `distutils.cfg` and put inside

  ```
  [build]
  compiler=msvc
  ```
- `python setup.py install`