# Should gcc find Python.h without being passed -I/usr/include/python2.7/?

Tags: python, c++, c, gcc

I wrote a small c program on RedHat:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, Python!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And got the following error:

> main.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

So I found the following answer: [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Installed python-devel. I verify that `/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h` exists, and still getting the same error.

Of-course when running `gcc main.c -I/usr/include/python2.7/` everything compiles fine.

**My question is:**

Is it correct to add `-I/usr/include/python2.7/` when compiling, or is there some kind of built-in env-variable that gcc should expect (something like PYTHON_DEV_HOME).

*This is kinda strange question I believe, but the reason I'm asking is because I'm getting the same error for TensorFlow (git cloned), which should be compiling off the bat. Since it isn't, I assume my environment is missing somthing...*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530866/674064 seems to indicate that this is normal.

Comment: Don't set any environment variabes, pass `-I/usr/include/python2.7` to gcc explicitly. Write a makefile to automate the task. If you are creating real software that other people can build on their machines, you need some kind of auto-configuration tool that builds a makefile or a similar build script automatically according to local environment. If you are just learning you can also just use `#include <python2.7/Python.h> instead of all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly normal.

You cannot expect `gcc` to read Python environment variables - `gcc` is independent of Python and has no connection to it.  Python can use `gcc`, as do (probably) thousands of other products, but other compilers should be usable as well.

`gcc` environment variables are listed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html).  Take a look at `CPATH` which can be used instead of `-I`, but make sure you read exactly what it does.  `C_INCLUDE_PATH` is an alternative.

Comment: The argument is actually the other way around - GCC can use thousands of libraries, some of which didn't even exist when GCC itself was built. How is GCC going to know about `/usr/include/RattleSnake1.0` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should normally specify it with -I, but - to answer the question - you can also set CPATH environment variable:

```
export CPATH=:/usr/include/python2.7/
```

and gcc will search this directory for includes without any additional switches.