# showing error while trying to install jupyter in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter

Command : sudopip install jupyter

```
Error :
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-En0PFz/scandir/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-OVVJzg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying scandir.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    running build_ext
    building '_scandir' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _scandir.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_scandir.o
    _scandir.c:14:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-En0PFz/scandir/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-OVVJzg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-En0PFz/scandir/
```

Comment: you'll need at least the python-dev package..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: tnx @thebjorn problem solve with sudo apt-get install python3-dev

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

and then:

```
    $ sudo pip install jupyter
```