# Compile Cython Extensions Error - Pycharm IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, pycharm, cython

> **Non-zero exit code (1):** 
>   _pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.c:13:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status **1**

Please help me resolve this error of trying to install Cython in PyCharm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 50):

JetBrains has provided an answer:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.3/cython-speedups.html

If you're on Ubuntu, run:

For Python 2.7: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

For Python 3.5: `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

For Python 3.6: `sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev`

For Python 3.7: `sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev`

Comment: If using a virtualenv you might have to do the above after activating the env.

Comment: For RHEL / CentOS it's named "-devel", e.g. `sudo yum install python36-devel`

Comment: In my case `sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev` solved the issue

Comment: For Python 3.8, I had to run `sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev`

Comment: Thanks!
Currently for python2.7 on Ubuntu use `python2-dev`

Answer (score 3):

For python 3.7  `sudo apt install libpython3.7-dev`
solved my problem

Comment: It does not work for me, "Couldn't locate package libpython3.7-dev"

Answer (score 3):

Every time PyCharm makes an IDE update, I spend endless hours searching for how to do it again in Linux.

I'd like to register my answer here for my own self next time.

1. You have to use the system `python`.
2. Before anything, you have to have `sudo apt-get install python<your_bin_version>-dev`
   Obs. Use `which python` at `usr/bin` to find out.
3. However, the system `python` does not recognize `conda setuptools`.
4. Thus, you also need `sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`

After that, if  you run, the updated place of PyCharm help, as such:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python3 /<your_pycharm_installation_dir>/pycharm-2021.1/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py build_ext --inplace
```

Then, and only then, it works ... (but only for the base python).

Next, I found the recently constructed directory `/_pydevd_bundle` and manually (yeah) copied it into

```
/<your conda environmenbt>/.conda/envs/py39web/compiler_compat
```

Except for jupyter notebooks, though.

Answer (score 2):

Works also for Python 3.9

```
sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev
```

Comment: We don't need to add an answer for every minor version of Python. One would expect this syntax to continue to work going forward unless something changes. If it's really necessary, though, you can propose an edit to the accepted answer so include this.