# Compile Cython Extensions Error - Pycharm IDE. Linux Mint

Tags: python, linux, gcc, pycharm, cython

```
Non-zero exit code (1): 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/snap/pycharm-community/315/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py", line 242, in   main() 
File "/snap/pycharm-community/315/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py", line 233, in main with FrameEvalModuleBuildContext(): 
File "/snap/pycharm-community/315/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py", line 187, in __enter__ shutil.copy(compatible_c, self._c_file) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 427, in copy copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 266, in copyfile with 
open(dst, 'wb') as fdst: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/snap/pycharm-community/315/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_frame_eval/pydevd_frame_evaluator.c'
```

I did as [written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257766/compile-cython-extensions-error-pycharm-ide?newreg=ee20b1b72ba84b8fa44265ef61aeff98) here, but it doesn't work yet.

Please tell me what else can be done.