# Centos7: python-ldap installation with pip

Tags: ldap, pip, virtualenv, openldap, python-ldap

I have asked this question before and was solved by `gcc` installation but I am currently migrating the app to production machine.

I have installed `gcc`, `python-devel`, `openssl-devel`, `kernel-devel`, `openldap-devel`, I even tried `yum groupinstall "Development tools"` but to no avail

```
[root@test myproject]# venv/bin/pip install python-ldap
Collecting python-ldap
  Using cached python-ldap-2.5.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-ldap)
Installing collected packages: python-ldap
  Running setup.py install for python-ldap ... error
    Complete output from command /home/user/myproject/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tyzjnz/python-ldap/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ji9sPr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user/myproject/venv/include/site/python2.7/python-ldap:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib/ldap/ldapobject.py (for module ldap.ldapobject) not found
    file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying Lib/ldapurl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying Lib/ldif.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying Lib/slapdtest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    copying Lib/ldap/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    copying Lib/ldap/async.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/deref.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/libldap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/openldap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/ppolicy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/psearch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/pwdpolicy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/readentry.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/sessiontrack.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/simple.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/sss.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/controls/vlv.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/controls
    copying Lib/ldap/cidict.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    copying Lib/ldap/dn.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/extop
    copying Lib/ldap/extop/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/extop
    copying Lib/ldap/extop/dds.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/extop
    copying Lib/ldap/filter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    copying Lib/ldap/functions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/ldapobject
    copying Lib/ldap/ldapobject/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/ldapobject
    copying Lib/ldap/ldapobject/simple.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/ldapobject
    copying Lib/ldap/ldapobject/reconnect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/ldapobject
    copying Lib/ldap/logger.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    copying Lib/ldap/modlist.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    copying Lib/ldap/pkginfo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    copying Lib/ldap/resiter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    copying Lib/ldap/sasl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/schema
    copying Lib/ldap/schema/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/schema
    copying Lib/ldap/schema/models.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/schema
    copying Lib/ldap/schema/subentry.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/schema
    copying Lib/ldap/schema/tokenizer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap/schema
    copying Lib/ldap/syncrepl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ldap
    file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib/ldap/ldapobject.py (for module ldap.ldapobject) not found
    file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib/ldap/ldapobject.py (for module ldap.ldapobject) not found
    file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    reading manifest file 'Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'
    warning: no files found matching 'Modules/LICENSE'
    writing manifest file 'Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building '_ldap' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_SASL -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.5.2 -DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project -DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style -IModules -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sasl -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/LDAPObject.o
    In file included from Modules/LDAPObject.c:3:0:
    Modules/common.h:9:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/user/myproject/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tyzjnz/python-ldap/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ji9sPr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user/myproject/venv/include/site/python2.7/python-ldap" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tyzjnz/python-ldap/
```

`yum install python-ldap` is successful so I guess the issue is with `pip` but I need it to install in my virtual environment. I have successfully installed the package with `pip` in my test machine but can't install in production.

Need serious help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Seems like it.  i get the same error and that link fixes it.  But i fix it (following that link) by installing `python-devel`.  OP says he has done that and is still getting the error.  Can he confirm that?