# pip install pandas without upgrading pip

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am now trying to run a program on a super computer on which I cannot run sudo or easy_install. The program needs pandas so I need to pip install pandas but I keep getting this error message even thought I have tried "pip install --upgrade pip" already.

> You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

--edit--
Here is the error message when I pip3 install pandas.

```
pip3 install pandas
Collecting pandas
Using cached pandas-0.22.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Running from numpy source directory.
/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/setup.py:369: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
  run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 239, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 269, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 238, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/setup.py", line 394, in <module>

  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/setup.py", line 386, in setup_package

  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 151, in run
    self.run_command("egg_info")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 26, in run
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 165, in build_sources
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 324, in build_extension_sources
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 422, in generate_config_h
    return tag
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 48, in check_types
    min_numpy_ver = '1.9.0'
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 281, in check_types
    pjoin(ujson_lib,'ultrajsondec.c'),
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-xqyfs1o1/pandas/setup.py", line 743, in <module>
    **setuptools_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 312, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1091, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1103, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 379, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 638, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 668, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 851, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1079, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1065, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in run_setup
    raise
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    compat.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/compat.py", line 69, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 239, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 269, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 238, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/setup.py", line 394, in <module>

  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/setup.py", line 386, in setup_package

  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 151, in run
    self.run_command("egg_info")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 26, in run
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 165, in build_sources
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 324, in build_extension_sources
  File "/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 422, in generate_config_h
    return tag
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 48, in check_types
    min_numpy_ver = '1.9.0'
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 281, in check_types
    pjoin(ujson_lib,'ultrajsondec.c'),
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/temp/tmpsx06jzi5/source.c:1:19: fatal error: cblas.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cblas.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/temp/tmpsx06jzi5/source.c:1:19: fatal error: cblas.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cblas.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
_configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’
 int exp (void);
     ^~~
_configtest.o: In function `main':
/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
_configtest.o: In function `main':
/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
_configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’
 int exp (void);
     ^~~
_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-build-xqyfs1o1/pandas/
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: You dont need to upgrade pip to install pandas.. it's just a recommendation since you don't have the latest version

Comment: Just edited the question with the error message when I tried to pip3 install pandas.

Comment: This is your actual error: `_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>`   ---- you're missing your python header files

Comment: [Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768/4889267)

Comment: Well, the problem is I cannot run in sudo mode:(

Comment: It's actually recommended in your error too: `SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
/tmp/easy_install-gv5il123/numpy-1.14.1/temp/tmpsx06jzi5/source.c:1:19: fatal error: cblas.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cblas.h>`

Comment: Can you do `pip install python-dev`? ---Edit: actually, you will probably need sudo permissions to execute this

Comment: No:( "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-dev (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-dev"

Comment: This is definitely the solution to your problem - keep hunting. You need to install something else which adds the distribution - possibly dev tools or something?

Comment: you could try "conda" if you have installed anaconda ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the packages `python-dev` and `python-devel`. 
But since you are not root on that server you probably cannot install them yourself. Basically you could ask the administrator if he could install them for you. 
I would recommend installing a local version of Python and install the packages there.
By the way: Since you are not root `pip` would fail anyways since you probably do not have the right to globally install packages. You should use pip install `<package> --user` instead.