# Pip install PyAudio fails with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

Hi I Just Tried to install **PyAudio** on my new Linux Mint 18 Installation. I had first installed **python-pip** from the repositories, then installed **setuptools** python package. When i tried to install **PyAudio** it returns that module setuptools dosent exist. Can Anyone Please help me out with this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMUvb.jpg)

error_log(command line log): http://www.textsnip.com/yuila1

Comment: Can you post your command line and error message.  No screen shot please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: The command line error is in the error log link.