# Unable to install matplotlib on aws linux server

Tags: matplotlib

I tried below command to install install matplotlib on linux server but its failing.. guide to resolve this issue.

```
python -mpip install matplotlib
RuntimeError: sh ./configure failed.
```

---

```
Failed building wheel for subprocess32
  Running setup.py clean for subprocess32
Failed to build subprocess32
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires argparse, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires cheetah, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires oauth, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires PrettyTable, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires pyserial, which is not installed.
```

---

---

> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-Ex80fQ/subprocess32/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-record-lOrC6I/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-Ex80fQ/subprocess32/

Answer (score 0):

Try with sudo apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the AWS linux image you are using doesn't have a C compiler installed.

To install, it depends on your distro but for me:
`sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`

Afterwards I had to also install header files for python dev: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768