# Installing issue with cyordereddict

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip

I am on `Ubuntu 16.04`, `python 2.7`.
I couldn’t able to install `cyordereddict`

```
sudo python -m pip install cyordereddict
The directory '/home/amitn/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/amitn/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting cyordereddict
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/1a/364cbfd927be1b743c7f0a985a7f1f7e8a51469619f9fefe4ee9240ba210/cyordereddict-1.0.0.tar.gz (138kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 592kB/s 
Installing collected packages: cyordereddict
  Running setup.py install for cyordereddict ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-Pslw4h/cyordereddict/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-jxtmtk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict
    copying python2/cyordereddict/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict
    copying python2/cyordereddict/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict/benchmark
    copying python2/cyordereddict/benchmark/magic_timeit.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict/benchmark
    copying python2/cyordereddict/benchmark/benchmark.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict/benchmark
    copying python2/cyordereddict/benchmark/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict/benchmark
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict/test
    copying python2/cyordereddict/test/_mapping_tests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict/test
    copying python2/cyordereddict/test/test_ordereddict.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict/test
    copying python2/cyordereddict/test/_test_support.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict/test
    copying python2/cyordereddict/test/test_cyordereddict.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict/test
    copying python2/cyordereddict/test/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cyordereddict/test
    running build_ext
    building 'cyordereddict._cyordereddict' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/python2
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/python2/cyordereddict
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c python2/cyordereddict/_cyordereddict.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/python2/cyordereddict/_cyordereddict.o
    python2/cyordereddict/_cyordereddict.c:12:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-Pslw4h/cyordereddict/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-jxtmtk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-Pslw4h/cyordereddict/
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: thanks for quick help. I got my solution. yay!

Comment: glad I could help!

Comment: Well what was the solution?

Comment: @JayTurnr refer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory