# Installation of Python ODBC (pyodbc) failed on the Linux Server Centos

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to install the pyodbc (Python ODBC) on the Linux Centos machine. But i am getting below error when i run the command "pip install pyodbc". Python 3.6.5 is already installed on my machine.

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED                                                                                                                     =1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-prot                                                                                                                     ector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic                                                                                                                      -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.24 -I/usr/include/python                                                                                                                     3.6m -c src/getdata.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/getdata.o -Wno-write-                                                                                                                     strings -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -DHAVE_PWD_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_LONG_LONG -DSIZEO                                                                                                                     F_LONG_INT=8 -I/usr/include
In file included from src/getdata.cpp:5:0:
src/pyodbc.h:45:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

[root@ip-172-31-33-62 centos]# python3.6 -V
Python 3.6.5

Comment: You may need to install your distro's `python-dev` package.

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory