# File python.h not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, anaconda, macports

I am trying to run gnu make, however it says that it can't find the python.h file, which I assume is a result of Python not being correctly installed.

I struggled over finding the best way to install Python, installing it via macports initially in version 3.6, and then installing anaconda as I was using pycharm and it made installing packages a lot easier, although I feel like my Python installation could now be causing confusion.

`python --version` returns: `Python 3.7.3`

`cat .bash_profile` returns:

`````
##
# Your previous /Users/jonathandyke/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/jonathandyke/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2019-06-30_at_22:20:05
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2019-06-30_at_22:20:05: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<````
`````

Comment: what is the result of: type python in cli?

Comment: ````Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.````

Comment: it is not the result of: 'type python' run in cli.

Comment: Sorry, misread, ````python is hashed (/anaconda3/bin/python)````

Comment: Try installing `python3-devel` package.

Comment: it means your are using the python from above path. why don't you try: conda create --name py36 python=3.6 and then run source activate py36?

Comment: @szerszen I am still getting the ````Fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found```` when running ````make````

Comment: what do you make? can you share the script you are executing with make?

Comment: I am trying to complete 6.2 in this: http://www.festvox.org/docs/manual-2.4.0/festival_6.html#Installation where I have replaced gmake with make

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

you might have messed up the header files somehow. Try

```
brew uninstall python3
brew install python3
```

if you are on ubuntu
`apt-get install python3-dev` should do it