# How to properly install TrustTrees library in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, pip

TrustTrees is a subdomain enumeration tool based on python. When I am installing TrustTrees python library, error message is showing. I have no idea how to solve it. Following are the error trace.

```
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-f5wljx0z --python-tag cp36
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/
  Complete output (50 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/agraph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/graphviz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_node_attributes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_html.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_string.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_subgraph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_layout.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_edge_attributes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_attribute_defaults.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_graph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_attributes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_drawing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_clear.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_readwrite.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/tests
  running egg_info
  writing pygraphviz.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
  writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying pygraphviz/graphviz.i -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
  running build_ext
  building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o
  pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:130:11: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   # include <Python.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
  Running setup.py clean for pygraphviz
Failed to build pygraphviz
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz, TrustTrees
    Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-oysqalc0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/
    Complete output (29 lines):
    running install
    Trying pkg-config
    Package libcgraph was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcgraph.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libcgraph' found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/setup.py", line 87, in <module>
        tests_require=['nose>=0.10.1', 'doctest-ignore-unicode>=0.1.0',],
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/setup_commands.py", line 44, in modified_run
        self.include_path, self.library_path = get_graphviz_dirs()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/setup_extra.py", line 121, in get_graphviz_dirs
        include_dirs, library_dirs = _pkg_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/setup_extra.py", line 44, in _pkg_config
        output = S.check_output(['pkg-config', '--libs-only-L', 'libcgraph'])
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
        output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', '--libs-only-L', 'libcgraph']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m199of9z/pygraphviz/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-oysqalc0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Seems like I am getting compilation error for graphviz python library. I have installed it, but still the error message is same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+Python.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory