# `make` error when compiling vim with python3 support

Tags: vim, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to compile vim with python3 support.

I cloned vim: `git clone https://github.com/vim/vim` and ran:

```
./configure --enable-python3interp
```

Output:

```
configure: loading cache auto/config.cache
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... (cached) o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... (cached) none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... (cached) gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... (cached) /bin/grep
checking for egrep... (cached) /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... (cached) /bin/grep -F
checking for library containing strerror... (cached) none required
checking for gawk... (cached) mawk
checking for strip... (cached) strip
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... (cached) yes
checking for unsigned long long int... (cached) yes
checking for long long int... (cached) yes
checking if the compiler supports trailing commas... yes
checking if the compiler supports C++ comments... yes
checking --enable-fail-if-missing argument... no
checking for clang version... N/A
configure: checking for buggy tools...
checking for BeOS... no
checking for QNX... no
checking for Darwin (Mac OS X)... no
checking for AvailabilityMacros.h... (cached) no
checking --with-local-dir argument... Defaulting to /usr/local
checking --with-vim-name argument... Defaulting to vim
checking --with-ex-name argument... Defaulting to ex
checking --with-view-name argument... Defaulting to view
checking --with-global-runtime argument... no
checking --with-modified-by argument... no
checking if character set is EBCDIC... no
checking --disable-smack argument... no
checking for linux/xattr.h... (cached) yes
checking for attr/xattr.h... (cached) no
checking --disable-selinux argument... no
checking for is_selinux_enabled in -lselinux... (cached) no
checking --with-features argument... Defaulting to huge
checking --with-compiledby argument... no
checking --disable-xsmp argument... no
checking --disable-xsmp-interact argument... no
checking --enable-luainterp argument... no
checking --enable-mzschemeinterp argument... no
checking --enable-perlinterp argument... no
checking --enable-pythoninterp argument... no
checking --enable-python3interp argument... yes
checking --with-python3-command argument... no
checking Python version... (cached) 3.6
checking Python is 3.0 or better... yep
checking Python's abiflags... (cached) m
checking Python's install prefix... (cached) /home/user/venvs/fundreader
checking Python's execution prefix... (cached) /home/user/venvs/fundreader
(cached) checking Python's configuration directory... (cached) /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu
(cached) checking Python3's dll name... (cached) libpython3.6m.a
checking if -pthread should be used... yes
checking if compile and link flags for Python 3 are sane... yes
checking if -fPIE can be added for Python3... yes
checking --enable-tclinterp argument... no
checking --enable-rubyinterp argument... no
checking --enable-cscope argument... no
checking --disable-netbeans argument... no
checking --disable-channel argument... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... (cached) no
checking for gethostbyname in -lnsl... (cached) yes
checking whether compiling with process communication is possible... yes
checking --enable-terminal argument... defaulting to yes
checking --enable-autoservername argument... no
checking --enable-multibyte argument... yes
checking --disable-rightleft argument... no
checking --disable-arabic argument... no
checking --enable-xim argument... defaulting to auto
checking --enable-fontset argument... no
checking for xmkmf... no
checking for X... (cached) libraries , headers 
checking for gethostbyname... (cached) yes
checking for connect... (cached) yes
checking for remove... (cached) yes
checking for shmat... (cached) yes
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... (cached) yes
checking if X11 header files can be found... yes
checking for _XdmcpAuthDoIt in -lXdmcp... (cached) yes
checking for IceOpenConnection in -lICE... (cached) yes
checking for XpmCreatePixmapFromData in -lXpm... (cached) yes
checking if X11 header files implicitly declare return values... no
checking size of wchar_t is 2 bytes... (cached) no
checking --enable-gui argument... yes/auto - automatic GUI support
checking whether or not to look for GTK+ 2... yes
checking whether or not to look for GNOME... no
checking whether or not to look for Motif... yes
checking whether or not to look for Athena... yes
checking whether or not to look for neXtaw... yes
checking whether or not to look for Carbon... yes
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking --disable-gtktest argument... gtk test enabled
no
checking for location of Motif GUI includes... <not found>
checking if Athena header files can be found... no
checking if neXtaw header files can be found... no
checking for X11/SM/SMlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for X11/xpm.h... (cached) yes
checking for X11/Sunkeysym.h... (cached) yes
checking for XIMText in X11/Xlib.h... yes
checking for /proc link to executable... /proc/self/exe
checking for CYGWIN or MSYS environment... no
checking whether toupper is broken... (cached) no
checking whether __DATE__ and __TIME__ work... yes
checking whether __attribute__((unused)) is allowed... yes
checking for elf.h... (cached) yes
checking for main in -lelf... (cached) no
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... (cached) yes
checking for library containing opendir... (cached) none required
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/select.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... (cached) yes
checking for termcap.h... (cached) yes
checking for fcntl.h... (cached) yes
checking for sgtty.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/time.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for termio.h... (cached) yes
checking for iconv.h... (cached) yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for langinfo.h... (cached) yes
checking for math.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for stropts.h... (cached) yes
checking for errno.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/resource.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/systeminfo.h... (cached) no
checking for locale.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/stream.h... (cached) no
checking for termios.h... (cached) yes
checking for libc.h... (cached) no
checking for sys/statfs.h... (cached) yes
checking for poll.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/poll.h... (cached) yes
checking for pwd.h... (cached) yes
checking for utime.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/ptms.h... (cached) no
checking for libintl.h... (cached) yes
checking for libgen.h... (cached) yes
checking for util/debug.h... (cached) no
checking for util/msg18n.h... (cached) no
checking for frame.h... (cached) no
checking for sys/acl.h... (cached) no
checking for sys/access.h... (cached) no
checking for sys/sysinfo.h... (cached) yes
checking for wchar.h... (cached) yes
checking for wctype.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/ptem.h... (cached) no
checking for sys/sysctl.h... (cached) yes
checking for pthread_np.h... no
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking if strings.h can be included after string.h... yes
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... (cached) no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... (cached) yes
checking for working volatile... (cached) yes
checking for mode_t... (cached) yes
checking for off_t... (cached) yes
checking for pid_t... (cached) yes
checking for size_t... (cached) yes
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for uint32_t... (cached) yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... (cached) yes
checking for ino_t... (cached) yes
checking for dev_t... (cached) yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... (cached) no
checking for inline... (cached) inline
checking for rlim_t... (cached) yes
checking for stack_t... (cached) yes
checking whether stack_t has an ss_base field... no
checking --with-tlib argument... empty: automatic terminal library selection
checking for tgetent in -ltinfo... (cached) yes
checking whether we talk terminfo... (cached) yes
checking what tgetent() returns for an unknown terminal... (cached) zero
checking whether termcap.h contains ospeed... yes
checking whether termcap.h contains UP, BC and PC... yes
checking whether tputs() uses outfuntype... no
checking whether sys/select.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for /dev/ptc... no
checking for SVR4 ptys... yes
checking for ptyranges... don't know
checking default tty permissions/group... (cached) world
checking return type of signal handlers... (cached) void
checking for struct sigcontext... yes
checking getcwd implementation is broken... (cached) no
checking for fchdir... (cached) yes
checking for fchown... (cached) yes
checking for fchmod... (cached) yes
checking for fsync... (cached) yes
checking for getcwd... (cached) yes
checking for getpseudotty... (cached) no
checking for getpwent... (cached) yes
checking for getpwnam... (cached) yes
checking for getpwuid... (cached) yes
checking for getrlimit... (cached) yes
checking for gettimeofday... (cached) yes
checking for localtime_r... (cached) yes
checking for lstat... (cached) yes
checking for memset... (cached) yes
checking for mkdtemp... (cached) yes
checking for nanosleep... (cached) yes
checking for opendir... (cached) yes
checking for putenv... (cached) yes
checking for qsort... (cached) yes
checking for readlink... (cached) yes
checking for select... (cached) yes
checking for setenv... (cached) yes
checking for getpgid... (cached) yes
checking for setpgid... (cached) yes
checking for setsid... (cached) yes
checking for sigaltstack... (cached) yes
checking for sigstack... (cached) yes
checking for sigset... (cached) yes
checking for sigsetjmp... (cached) no
checking for sigaction... (cached) yes
checking for sigprocmask... (cached) yes
checking for sigvec... (cached) no
checking for strcasecmp... (cached) yes
checking for strerror... (cached) yes
checking for strftime... (cached) yes
checking for stricmp... (cached) no
checking for strncasecmp... (cached) yes
checking for strnicmp... (cached) no
checking for strpbrk... (cached) yes
checking for strptime... (cached) yes
checking for strtol... (cached) yes
checking for tgetent... (cached) yes
checking for towlower... (cached) yes
checking for towupper... (cached) yes
checking for iswupper... (cached) yes
checking for tzset... (cached) yes
checking for usleep... (cached) yes
checking for utime... (cached) yes
checking for utimes... (cached) yes
checking for mblen... (cached) yes
checking for ftruncate... (cached) yes
checking for unsetenv... (cached) yes
checking for posix_openpt... (cached) yes
checking for sys/select.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/socket.h... (cached) yes
checking types of arguments for select... (cached) int,fd_set *,struct timeval *
checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... (cached) no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... (cached) no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... (cached) no
checking --enable-canberra argument... Defaulting to yes
checking for libcanberra... no; try installing libcanberra-dev
checking for st_blksize... yes
checking whether stat() ignores a trailing slash... (cached) no
checking for iconv_open()... yes
checking for nl_langinfo(CODESET)... yes
checking for strtod in -lm... (cached) yes
checking for strtod() and other floating point functions... yes
checking for isinf()... yes
checking for isnan()... yes
checking --disable-acl argument... no
checking for acl_get_file in -lposix1e... (cached) no
checking for acl_get_file in -lacl... (cached) no
checking for POSIX ACL support... no
checking for acl_get in -lsec... (cached) no
checking for Solaris ACL support... no
checking for AIX ACL support... no
checking --disable-gpm argument... no
checking for gpm... (cached) no
checking --disable-sysmouse argument... no
checking for sysmouse... (cached) no
checking for FD_CLOEXEC... yes
checking for rename... yes
checking for sysctl... not usable
checking for sysinfo... yes
checking for sysinfo.mem_unit... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking size of int... (cached) 4
checking size of long... (cached) 8
checking size of time_t... (cached) 8
checking size of off_t... (cached) 8
checking uint32_t is 32 bits... ok
checking whether memmove handles overlaps... (cached) yes
checking whether X_LOCALE needed... no
checking whether Xutf8SetWMProperties() can be used... yes
checking for _xpg4_setrunelocale in -lxpg4... (cached) no
checking how to create tags... ctags
checking how to run man with a section nr... man -s
checking --disable-nls argument... no
checking for msgfmt... (cached) msgfmt
checking for NLS... gettext() works
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... (cached) yes
checking for _nl_msg_cat_cntr... yes
checking if msgfmt supports --desktop... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... (cached) yes
checking for dlopen()... no
checking for dlopen() in -ldl... yes
checking for dlsym()... yes
checking for setjmp.h... (cached) yes
checking for GCC 3 or later... yes
checking whether we need -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1... yes
checking whether we need to force -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64... no
checking linker --as-needed support... yes
configure: creating auto/config.status
config.status: creating auto/config.mk
config.status: creating auto/config.h
config.status: auto/config.h is unchanged
```

Then, I typed `make` and obtained this error message:

```
Starting make in the src directory.
If there are problems, cd to the src directory and run make there
cd src && make first
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/user/vimtemp/src »
creating auto/pathdef.c
gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1        -o objects/pathdef.o auto/pathdef.c
gcc -c -I. -I/home/user/venvs/fundreader/include/python3.6m -pthread -fPIE  -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1        -o objects/if_python3.o if_python3.c
if_python3.c:69:10: fatal error: Python.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:3266: recipe for target 'objects/if_python3.o' failed
make[1]: *** [objects/if_python3.o] Error 1
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/user/vimtemp/src »
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'first' failed
make: *** [first] Error 2
```

How to make `make` run without errors so that I can run `make install`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+fatal+error%3A+Python.h

Answer (score 0):

You manually installed Python-3.6m into directory `/home/user/venvs/fundreader/` but the installation was incomplete: file `/home/user/venvs/fundreader/include/python-3.6m/Python.h` was not created.

(Also please read this: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0007 )