# I cannot install cupy with pip

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, cupy

I have attached the error message because I have no idea where to start with it. I have tried updating setuptools and purging and reinstalling pip.

I am running Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon 4.4.8.

If anyone has experienced this problem or has any suggestions for solutions, answers are much appreciated.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: cupy
  Building wheel for cupy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u16qlzud/cupy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u16qlzud/cupy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-l4z23_lk
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-u16qlzud/cupy/
  Complete output (322 lines):
  Options: {'package_name': 'cupy', 'long_description': None, 'wheel_libs': [], 'wheel_includes': [], 'no_rpath': False, 'profile': False, 'linetrace': False, 'annotate': False, 'no_cuda': False, 'use_hip': False}

  -------- Configuring Module: cuda --------

  -------- Configuring Module: cusolver --------

  -------- Configuring Module: cudnn --------
  /tmp/tmp1qjn9w6q/a.cpp:1:10: fatal error: cudnn.h: No such file or directory
   #include <cudnn.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  -------- Configuring Module: nccl --------
  /tmp/tmp2iuqiy0h/a.cpp:1:10: fatal error: nccl.h: No such file or directory
   #include <nccl.h>
            ^~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  -------- Configuring Module: nvtx --------

  -------- Configuring Module: thrust --------

  -------- Configuring Module: cutensor --------
  /tmp/tmp_s6hfvnf/a.cpp:1:10: fatal error: cutensor.h: No such file or directory
   #include <cutensor.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  -------- Configuring Module: cub --------
  /tmp/tmpuygeof24/a.cpp:1:10: fatal error: cub/util_namespace.cuh: No such file or directory
   #include <cub/util_namespace.cuh>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ************************************************************
  * CuPy Configuration Summary                               *
  ************************************************************

  Build Environment:
    Include directories: ['/usr/local/cuda/include']
    Library directories: ['/usr/local/cuda/lib64']
    nvcc command       : ['/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc']

  Environment Variables:
    CFLAGS          : (none)
    LDFLAGS         : (none)
    LIBRARY_PATH    : (none)
    CUDA_PATH       : (none)
    NVTOOLSEXT_PATH : (none)
    NVCC            : (none)
    ROCM_HOME       : (none)

  Modules:
    cuda      : Yes (version 10020)
    cusolver  : Yes
    cudnn     : No
      -> Include files not found: ['cudnn.h']
      -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.
    nccl      : No
      -> Include files not found: ['nccl.h']
      -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.
    nvtx      : Yes
    thrust    : Yes
    cutensor  : No
      -> Include files not found: ['cutensor.h']
      -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.
    cub       : No
      -> Include files not found: ['cub/util_namespace.cuh']
      -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.

  WARNING: Some modules could not be configured.
  CuPy will be installed without these modules.
  Please refer to the Installation Guide for details:
  https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html

  ************************************************************
```

Then it continues for a while without error, listing files it's copying (can't paste the whole thing because of character limits) and outputs this:

```
O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -D_FORCE_INLINES=1 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c cupy/core/_dtype.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cupy/core/_dtype.o
      cupy/core/_dtype.cpp:41:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       #include "Python.h"
                ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cupy
      Running setup.py clean for cupy
    Failed to build cupy
    Installing collected packages: cupy
        Running setup.py install for cupy ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u16qlzud/cupy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u16qlzud/cupy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-xu7deyq_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/rjyarwood/.local/include/python3.6m/cupy
             cwd: /tmp/pip-install-u16qlzud/cupy/
        Complete output (322 lines):
        Options: {'package_name': 'cupy', 'long_description': None, 'wheel_libs': [], 'wheel_includes': [], 'no_rpath': False, 'profile': False, 'linetrace': False, 'annotate': False, 'no_cuda': False, 'use_hip': False}

        -------- Configuring Module: cuda --------

        -------- Configuring Module: cusolver --------

        -------- Configuring Module: cudnn --------
        /tmp/tmp860stz4q/a.cpp:1:10: fatal error: cudnn.h: No such file or directory
         #include <cudnn.h>
                  ^~~~~~~~~
        compilation terminated.
        command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

        -------- Configuring Module: nccl --------
        /tmp/tmpgzs7nn1l/a.cpp:1:10: fatal error: nccl.h: No such file or directory
         #include <nccl.h>
                  ^~~~~~~~
        compilation terminated.
        command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

        -------- Configuring Module: nvtx --------

        -------- Configuring Module: thrust --------

        -------- Configuring Module: cutensor --------
        /tmp/tmp0evja8r4/a.cpp:1:10: fatal error: cutensor.h: No such file or directory
         #include <cutensor.h>
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
        compilation terminated.
        command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

        -------- Configuring Module: cub --------
        /tmp/tmpofwkp36s/a.cpp:1:10: fatal error: cub/util_namespace.cuh: No such file or directory
         #include <cub/util_namespace.cuh>
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        compilation terminated.
        command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

        ************************************************************
        * CuPy Configuration Summary                               *
        ************************************************************

        Build Environment:
          Include directories: ['/usr/local/cuda/include']
          Library directories: ['/usr/local/cuda/lib64']
          nvcc command       : ['/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc']

        Environment Variables:
          CFLAGS          : (none)
          LDFLAGS         : (none)
          LIBRARY_PATH    : (none)
          CUDA_PATH       : (none)
          NVTOOLSEXT_PATH : (none)
          NVCC            : (none)
          ROCM_HOME       : (none)

        Modules:
          cuda      : Yes (version 10020)
          cusolver  : Yes
          cudnn     : No
            -> Include files not found: ['cudnn.h']
            -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.
          nccl      : No
            -> Include files not found: ['nccl.h']
            -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.
          nvtx      : Yes
          thrust    : Yes
          cutensor  : No
            -> Include files not found: ['cutensor.h']
            -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.
          cub       : No
            -> Include files not found: ['cub/util_namespace.cuh']
            -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.

        WARNING: Some modules could not be configured.
        CuPy will be installed without these modules.
        Please refer to the Installation Guide for details:
        https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html

        ************************************************************
```

The does the same thing as before and then outputs this:

```
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cupy
        copying cupy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-
        building 'cupy.core._dtype' extension
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cupy
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cupy/core
        x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -D_FORCE_INLINES=1 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c cupy/core/_dtype.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cupy/core/_dtype.o
        cupy/core/_dtype.cpp:41:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
         #include "Python.h"
                  ^~~~~~~~~~
        compilation terminated.
        error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
        ----------------------------------------

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u16qlzud/cupy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u16qlzud/cupy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-xu7deyq_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/rjyarwood/.local/include/python3.6m/cupy Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+Python.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: Can you try to install a pre-built binary wheel?
it depends on the cuda version you have installed
For Cuda 10.0 `pip install cupy-cuda100` 
Cuda 10.1 `pip install cupy-cuda101`
Cuda 10.2 `pip install cupy-cuda102`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Python.h error, you probably need to install python3-dev (Debian/Ubuntu/Mint) or python3-devel (Fedora/CentOS/RHEL) using your operating system's package manager like apt or dnf.

For the other missing .h's, you can usually google for:

```
cudnn.h: No such file or directory Debian
```

...to find out which Debian package includes cudnn.h

HTH.

Comment: Seems a package like "libcuda-dev" doesn't exist for Debian / Debian clones. Suggest : Get the cuda headers from a source package https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Answer (score 3):

**RESOLVED ISSUE:** Check this [Doc](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/install.html?highlight=install#requirements). There was support issue with various cuda version.
CHECK "Installing CuPy"
FOR EXAMPLE: pip install cupy-cuda101