# Distribution format for Python libraries uploaded on PyPI

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging, twine

I went through the tutorial of uploading packages to https://test.pypi.org/ and I was successful in doing so.

However, `$python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` produces a `.whl` file and a `tar.gz` file in the `dist/` directory. `twine` allows uploading just the `.whl` or `tar.gz` file or both. I see many repositories on https://pypi.org/ have uploaded both the formats.

I want to understand what is the **best practice**. Is one format preferred over the other? If `.whl` file is enough for distributing my code, should I upload `tar.gz` file too? Or is there anything else I am completely missing here.

Comment: Twine should allow you to upload both, if you're not able to that might be a separate issue.

Comment: @DustinIngram yes, it allows uploading both. Perhaps, I should have been more clear. Thanks! I have updated that in the question.

Comment: Coincidentally there is an interesting ongoing discussion on the topic: https://discuss.python.org/t/purpose-of-an-sdist/4639

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice is to provide both.

A "built distribution" (`.whl`) for users that are able to use that distribution. This saves install time as a "built distribution" is pre-built and can just be dropped into place on the users machine, without any compilation step or without executing `setup.py`. There may be more than one built distribution for a given release -- once you start including compiled binaries with your distribution, they become platform-specific (see https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files for example)

A "source distribution" (`.tar.gz`) is essentially a fallback for any user that cannot use your built distribution(s). Source distributions are not "built" meaning they may require compilation to install. At the minimum, they require executing a build-backend (for most projects, this is invoking `setup.py` with `setuptools` as the build-backend). Any installer should be able to install from source. In addition, a source distribution makes it easier for users who want to audit your source code (although this is possible with built distributions as well).

For the majority of Python projects, turning a "source distribution" into a "built distribution" results in a single pure-Python wheel (which is indicated by the `none-any` in a filename like `projectname-1.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl`). There's not much difference between this and the source distribution, but it's still best practice to upload both.

Comment: Good answer (upvoted), except for one detail:  *At the minimum, they require executing the `setup.py` file* is no longer accurate. To give a counter-example, one of my projects has released [`pytest-raisin-0.3.tar.gz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-raisin/#files) and there is no setup.py file but it can still be installed from source distribution.

Comment: Sure, the point is still roughly the same though, you're still invoking _some_ build-backend, even if it doesn't have to be setuptools via `setup.py`. I'll update the answer to reflect that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A `.tar.gz` is a so called source distribution. It contains the source code of your package and instructions on how to build it, and the target system will perform the build before installing it.

A `.wheel` (spec details in [PEP 427](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/)) is a built distribution format, which means that the target system doesn't need to build it any more. Installing a wheel usually just means copying its content into the right `site-packages`.

The wheel sounds downright superior, because it is. It is still **best practice to upload both**, wheels and a source distribution, because any built distribution format only works for a subset of target systems. For a [package that contains only python code](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#pure-python-wheels), that subset is "everything" - people still often upload source distributions though, maybe to be forward compatible in case a new standard turns up<sup>[1]</sup>, maybe to anticipate [system specific extensions](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#platform-wheels) that will suddenly require source distributions in order to support all platforms, maybe to give users the option to run a custom build with specific build-parameters.

A good example package to observe the different cases is [numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files), which uploads a whooping 25 wheels to cover the most popular platforms, plus a source distribution. If you install numpy from any of the supported platforms, you'll get a nice short install taking a couple of second where the contents of the wheel are copied over. If you are on an unsupported platform (such as alpine), a normal computer will probably take at least 20 minutes to build numpy from source before it can be installed, and you need to have all kinds of [system level dev tools for building C-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768/962190) installed. A bit of a pain, but still better then not being able to install it all.

---

<sup>[1] <sub>After all, before wheel there was egg, and the adoption of the wheel format would have been a lot harder than it already was if package managers had decided to only upload egg distributions and no sources.</sub></sup>

Comment: Great answer, except this part: "_people still often upload source distributions though, maybe because of cargo cult_". Would that be fair to ask you to change this part? I don't think it's "_cargo cult_". Even for pure Python releases, it seems important to me to always publish _source distributions_ (except maybe to keep the source code of compiled extensions private). Say, in the future the community moves away from _wheel_ for another _built_ format, we would still have all the past _sdist_ at hand to rebuild all past releases in that newer format.

Comment: @sinoroc is wheel a lossy format for pure python packages? either way, you're probably right, I'll remove that part and add your point of better support in case of future packaging standards.

Comment: Thanks for taking my suggestion into consideration! -- I would say _wheel_ is always lossy (pure or not), since for example you lose the `setup.py`, or `pyproject.toml` and so on. As far as I understood, some people like having access to the _sdist_ in particular because it often contains the tests as well. It's part of my best practices to distribute the tests in the _sdist_ (not in the _wheel_ obviously).

Comment: Coincidentally there is an interesting ongoing discussion on the topic: https://discuss.python.org/t/purpose-of-an-sdist/4639

Answer (score -3):

You can just upload whl file and install with below command

Comment: I know that we can upload the `.whl` file, I would like to know the best practice. What is the reason behind uploading both when you can just do it with the `.whl` file