# How to fix missing "Python.h" on Arch Linux?

Tags: python, c, arch

Including "Python.h" in a C file:

```c
#include <Python.h>
```

gives `Python.h: No such file or directory` error.
I looked up for other people having the same problem and none gave a direct answer on how to install python*-dev (python2 and python3) on arch Linux. And by the way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory) answer doesn't have an arch installation command.

Comment: Are you familiar with [pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman)?

Comment: yea it's not a viable package

Comment: "a viable package"? How do you check exactly if something is a "viable package" or not? `gives Python.h: No such file or directory` What command exactly "gives"?

Comment: Take a look at the arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python

Comment: not a command, it's a C file

Comment: try `find -name Python.h`

Comment: /usr/include/python3.8/Python.h and why isn't this including exactly??? >:(

Comment: Please specify the command, compiler and compiler options you are using to compile the file. Please specify what command do you type in your terminal. `why isn't this including exactly?` Because the directory `/usr/include/python3.8` is not a default compiler search path.

Comment: Because `/usr/include/python3.8/` is not a standard place where header files are found. Read **all** the answers on the page you have linked to.

Comment: Pacman installs *packages,* not individual files. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14858/in-arch-linux-how-can-i-find-out-which-package-to-install-that-will-contain-file to find out the proper package name. See also https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=39935

Comment: ok how would I `correctly` include it? and I'm just running `gcc testing.c`

Comment: Try `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags python3) testing.c -o testing $(pkg-config --libs python3)`.

Comment: @IanAbbott :) thanks! can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out "Python.h" is already installed on Arch, but just wasn't in the standard header files location `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags python3) testing.c -o testing` solved it for me.