# Cannot find 'Python.h' after installation of python3-dev on ubuntu

Tags: python, gcc, python-c-api

I try to include `Python.h` for a c++ project.
I am on ubuntu 18.04, I installed python3-dev (as I have python3.6 on my system) and everything looks good, I can even locate the `Python.h` as shown in the image below. But cmake still complains it cannot find `Python.h`. Did I miss anything? I know I can use `-I` to pass the directory to gcc, but is it suppose to work right way after I have `python3-dev` installed and the header shows up under `usr/include`?

[image]

Comment: To find something freshly installed with `locate`, `updatedb` has to be run.

Comment: @KlausD. interestingly, my `locate updatedb` output does not list `usr/include`

Comment: Did you literally run `locate updatedb`?

Comment: yes, and not only that, i found i cannot locate any header file in `/usr/include`, basically the path cannot be found by locate or gcc by default

Comment: Note the space and comma! `updatedb` is a tool that updates the database for `locate`, without running it the search happens on old information. Usually it is run by cron periodically.

Comment: see my update in the post with output for updatedb

Comment: You should read more carefully!

Comment: sorry about that, after running `sudo updatedb` now i can locate the `Python.h` but gcc still cannot find it...

Comment: Just to add a bit of clarification - typically Python.h isn't added to the include path. This is so that you can have multiple versions of Python installed and they won't conflict. If you compile you an extension with setup.py then the version of Python you use will set it up automatically. Otherwise your best option is to call `gcc args $(python3-config --includes)` as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56508166/4657412)