# Dockerfile: Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a simple dockerfile that I am using to run containers on AWS, I'm hitting an issue though when installing `s3fs`, which is strange since I've used this snippet in previous dockerfiles without issue.

Is it something with the distribution?

Error:

```
multidict/_multidict.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest


RUN yum -y install which unzip aws-cli \
    && yum install -y python3-pip python3 python3-setuptools \
    && yum install -y tar.x86_64 \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive yum install -y ksh


RUN pip3 install boto3 \
    && yum install -y gcc \
    && pip3 install s3fs
```

Here is the output log:

```
Installing collected packages: fsspec, docutils, botocore, typing-extensions, aioitertools, wrapt, attrs, chardet, multidict, async-timeout, idna, yarl, aiohttp, aiobotocore, s3fs
  Found existing installation: botocore 1.19.11
    Uninstalling botocore-1.19.11:
      Successfully uninstalled botocore-1.19.11
  Running setup.py install for wrapt: started
    Running setup.py install for wrapt: finished with status 'done'
  Running setup.py install for multidict: started
    Running setup.py install for multidict: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-l35mgnnl/multidict/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7d6e5wlf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    **********************
    * Accellerated build *
    **********************
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict
    copying multidict/_abc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict
    copying multidict/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict
    copying multidict/_multidict_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict
    copying multidict/_multidict_py.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict
    copying multidict/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict
    running egg_info
    writing multidict.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/_multidict.html'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.so'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.pyd'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.pyd'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying multidict/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict
    copying multidict/_multidict.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict
    copying multidict/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict/_multilib
    copying multidict/_multilib/defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict/_multilib
    copying multidict/_multilib/dict.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict/_multilib
    copying multidict/_multilib/istr.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict/_multilib
    copying multidict/_multilib/iter.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict/_multilib
    copying multidict/_multilib/pair_list.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict/_multilib
    copying multidict/_multilib/views.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict/_multilib
    running build_ext
    building 'multidict._multidict' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c multidict/_multidict.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict/_multidict.o -O2 -std=c99 -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wconversion -fno-strict-aliasing -pedantic
    multidict/_multidict.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-l35mgnnl/multidict/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7d6e5wlf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-l35mgnnl/multidict/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install boto3     && yum install -y gcc     && pip3 install s3fs' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add `python3-devel` package that contains absent headers.

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest


RUN yum -y install which unzip aws-cli \
    && yum install -y python3-pip python3 python3-setuptools \
    && yum install -y python3-devel.x86_64 \
    && yum install -y tar.x86_64 \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive yum install -y ksh


RUN pip3 install boto3 \
    && yum install -y gcc \
    && pip3 install s3fs
```

Comment: sudo yum install python3-devel