# How to fix deeptoolsintervals fatal error: Python.h?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried installing `pip3 install deeptoolsintervals` the error is:

```
 deeptoolsintervals/tree/tree.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

I have Ubuntu 16.04.7 and Python versions installed:

```
ls /usr/bin | grep python

dh_python2
dh_python3
python
python2
python2.7
python2.7-config
python2-config
python3
python3.5
python3.5m
python3.9
python3m
python-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python-config
```

I have installed deeptools under python3.9

```
$ git clone https://github.com/deeptools/deepTools
$ cd deepTools
$ python3.9 setup.py install
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`, but it sets it up on python3.5 and when I run `pip3 install deeptoolsintervals`, I have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I was not using the same version of python each time, so I installed the python-env for python3.9

```
sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev
```

and then

```
pip3.9 install deeptoolsintervals
```

successfully installed.