# fatal error: os/rand.c: No such file or directory

Tags: pip, python-3.9

Regarding my last question [How to fix deeptoolsintervals fatal error: Python.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66546716/15036724),
when trying to run `plotCoverage.py`, I bumped into another error:

```
    import pysam
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysam'
```

when trying to install `pip3.9 install pysam`:

```
htslib/hts_os.c:30:21: fatal error: os/rand.c: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

Then I read somewhere that `apt-get install liblzma-dev` might fix this issue, although installed that successfully, I still have the same error when tying to install `pysam`.

Comment: `sudo apt install libbz2-dev` fixed the missing part