# Pip Install On Amazon Linux ec2 PEP 517 Error

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip, pep517

I'm trying to pip install autogluon on an amazon linux ec2 instance. All other pip installs have worked so far, but pip installing autogluon throws the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for bottleneck
Failed to build ConfigSpace psutil bottleneck
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ConfigSpace, bottleneck which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Is this an inherent issue when trying to install these packages on an ec2?

Comment: Can you try with `pip install --no-use-pep517 ...`

Comment: I tried that but I get a similar error error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ConfigSpace

Comment: You don't have a more detailed error message (perhaps from a build log)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Amazon Linux 2, install gcc

```
yum install gcc
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error and tried

```
sudo yum install python3-devel
```

and got autogluon installed!
[fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a `pip` issue, it's unlikely that it relates to the EC2 itself. Try the following:

```
python -m pip install pip --upgrade
python -m pip install autogluon --no-use-pep517
```

Comment: I tried this but then I get a similar error as before

  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ConfigSpace

I then tried to yum install gcc and attempt the pip install again but still was met with the same error